# Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java

Tags: java, книги, java-faq

Собираем подборку качественной литературы по **Java**.

Дописывайте, если есть что добавить в общий ответ.

---

> Данный перечень входит в поддерживаемый сообществом [Сборник учебных ресурсов по программированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683).

Answer (score 142, accepted):

## Core Java

### Начинающим:

- *Head First Java (2nd Edition)*. Kathy Sierra, Bert Bates.

  Русский перевод: *Изучаем Java*. Кэти Сиерра, Берт Бейтс.

  Как это обычно бывает в книгах *Head First*, вас весело и в картинках обучат основам программирования на Java. У опытных программистов книга может вызвать ухмылку, однако для действительно начального уровня она вполне хороша.
- *Java: A Beginner's Guide*. Herbert Schildt.

  Русский перевод: *Java. Руководство для начинающих*. Герберт Шилдт.
- *Core Java Volume I: Fundamentals (9th Edition), Core Java Volume II: Advanced Features (9th Edition)*.

  Русский перевод: *Java. Библиотека профессионала. Том 1. Основы; Java. Библиотека профессионала. Том 2. Расширенные средства программирования*. Кей С. Хорстманн, Гари Корнелл.

  Книги Хорстманна написаны достаточно сухим языком и вываливают на читателя горы документации по API и километры листингов с полным кодом примеров. Читать их последовательно может быть довольно тяжко, зато книги станут отличным настольным справочником и сборником рецептов.
- [*Java™ Platform, Standard Edition 7 API Specification*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/), [8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/), [9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/overview-summary.html), [10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/overview-summary.html), [11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/).

  Онлайн-документация по стандартным библиотекам JAVA SE.
- Yakov  Fain, *Java  Programming  for  Kids,  Parents  and  Grandparents*

  Русский перевод: Яков Файн, *Программирование на java для детей, родителей, бабушек и дедушек*

  Книга рассчитана на детей, в ней много картинок, её интересно читать. В первых главах автор объясняет основные конструкции языка, классы и объекты и так далее. В последующих главах читатель пишет вместе с автором несколько `swing`-программ, изучая параллельно важные темы. Вот что говорит про неё сам автор:

> Эта книга не охватывает все элементы языка Java. В противном
> случае, это сделало бы ее слишком толстой и скучной. Однако в
> конце  каждой главы помещен раздел с материалaми для
> дополнительного чтения, который содержит ссылки на
> англоязычные веб­‐сайты с более подробными сведениями о
> рассматриваемой теме.

#### Онлайн-курсы, учебники

- [Learn Java](https://dev.java/learn/) *(англ.)* официальные учебные пособия на dev.java
- [Уроки Java для начинающих](https://itproger.com/course/java) на itproger.com
- [Самоучитель по Java с нуля](https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/samouchitel-po-java-s-nulya/) - vertex-academy.com
- [Java Tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-tutorial) *(англ.)* на Javatpoint
- Курсы на Stepik.org:

  - [Java. Базовый курс](https://stepik.org/course/187) Computer Science Center (CS центр)
  - [Летняя Java школа](https://stepik.org/course/10498)
  - [Adaptive Java](https://stepik.org/course/2403/) *(англ.)* JetBrains
- [Hyperskill](https://hyperskill.org) *(англ.)* - сайт с учебными проектами для обучения программированию на Java, Kotlin, Python
- [JavaRush](https://javarush.ru)

### Средний уровень:

- *Thinking in Java (4th Edition)*. Bruce Eckel.

  Русский перевод: *Философия Java*. Брюс Эккель.

  Классический фолиант джавистов. Для комфортного чтения требуются базовые познания в языке, т.к. книга не ставит своей задачей научить писать на Java с нуля, а научить писать идиоматично.
- *Java 8: The Complete Reference*. Herbert Schildt.

  Русский перевод: *Java 8. Полное руководство*. Герберт Шилдт.
- *Effective Java (2nd Edition)*. Joshua Bloch.

  Русский перевод: *Java. Эффективное программирование*. Джошуа Блох.

  Джошуа Блох в некотором смысле продолжает идею книги *Thinking in Java*: еще сильнее углубляясь в особенности языка и стандартных библиотек, учит писать красивый код.
- *The Well-Grounded Java Developer: Vital techniques of Java 7 and polyglot programming*. Benjamin J Evans, Martijn Verburg.

  Русский перевод: *Java. Новое поколение разработки*. Бенджамин Эванс, Мартин Вербург.
- *Java Puzzlers: Traps, Pitfalls, and Corner Cases*. Joshua Bloch, Neal Gafter.

  *Java Puzzlers* дает возможность тем, кто уже "выучил язык" проверить себя. В книге собраны 95 задачек с подвохом: очевидные на первый взгляд фрагменты кода, таящие каверзный баг. Какие-то из рассматриваемых примеров могут показаться надуманными и нежизненными, однако они в полной мере раскрывают тонкие нюансы программирования на Java.
- *Java Concurrency in Practice*. Brian Goetz, Tim Peierls, Joshua Bloch, Joseph Bowbeer, David Holmes, Doug Lea.

  Подробнейшее пособие по написанию многопоточного кода на Java. Каждая тема рассматривается с разных сторон на нескольких примерах, так что к концу главы будет полное понимание осуждаемого предмета. Немаловажно, что один из соавторов (Doug Lea) является автором стандартной библиотеки concurrent-примитивов (`java.util.concurrent`).
- *Java Performance*. Charlie Hunt, Binu John.

  Must read по оптимизации java Программ, тюнингу JVM и сборщика мусора, бенчмаркингу и профилированию.
- *Core Java for the Impatient*. Cay Horstmann.

  Книга для нетерпеливых, как следует из названия. Позволяет погрузиться в мир языка Java, рассказывается всё, что на самом деле может пригодиться Java-разработчику. Отдельное внимание уделено новшествам восьмой версии языка. В конце каждой главы есть задания для более плотного усвоения материала. (Хорстманн не очень любит язык `C++`, иногда шутит по этому поводу, вроде того: `String[] badWords = {"sex", "drugs", "C++"};`, от этого читать становится не так скучно).
- *Java SE 8 for the Really Impatient*. Cay Horstmann.

  Русский перевод: *Java SE 8. Вводный курс Кей С. Хорстманна*

  Является продолжением книги *Core Java for the Impatient*, однако здесь всё внимание уделяется новшествам восьмой версии языка, покрывает очень многие аспекты, будь то лямбда-выражения, работа со `Stream API` или многопоточность. После каждой главы также присутствуют задания для усвоения материала.
- *Head First Design Patterns*.Eric Freeman, Elisabeth Robson, Bert Bates, Kathy Sierra.

  Русский перевод: Паттерны проектирования. Эрик Фримен, Элизабет Фримен

  Отличная книга от издательства O'Reilly, в веселой форме обучит вас основным   шаблонам проектирования на языке Java.
- *Java 8 Lambdas*. Richard Warburton.

  Русский перевод: Лямбда-выражения в Java 8. Ричард Уорбэртон

  Обычно в учебниках по Java мало внимания уделяют или не уделяют вовсе теме использования лямбд и стримов. Учебник Уорбэртона восполняет этот недостаток.

### Экспертный уровень:

- [*The Java Language Specification*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/index.html). James Gosling, Bill Joy, Guy L. Steele Jr., Gilad Bracha, Alex Buckley.
- [*The Java Virtual Machine Specification*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/index.html).  Tim Lindholm and Frank Yellin.
- *Oracle JRockit: The Definitive Guide*.  Marcus Hirt, Marcus Lagergren.

---

## Java EE

- [*Java™ Servlet Specification 3.1*](https://java.net/downloads/servlet-spec/Final/servlet-3_1-final.pdf)

  Исчерпывающая официальная документация о работе и жизненном цикле сервлетов.
- *Beginning Java EE 7*. Antonio Gonsalves.

  Русский перевод: *Изучаем Java EE 7*. Энтони Гонсалвес
- *Java EE 7. Основы* Арун Гупта
- *Head First Servlets and JSP, 2nd Edition*. Bryan Basham, Kathy Sierra, Bert Bates
- *Java Servlet and JSP Cookbook*. Bruce W. Perry

  Русский перевод: *Java сервлеты и JSP. Сборник рецептов*. Брюс У. Перри
- [*Java EE 8 SDK*](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-ee-sdk-download.html)

  Содержит в папке `docs` англоязычные руководства JavaEE Tutorial и FirstCup, а так же всё необходимое для изучения, с примерами готовых проектов на GlassFish. Онлайн версии так же доступны по адресу [Java EE Tutorial](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/)

---

## Spring

- [*Spring Projects*](https://spring.io/projects)

  Официальная документация о каждом проекте Spring. Описано подробно, но довольно сложно и много, поэтому для первого обучения рекомендую начать с [Spring Guides](https://spring.io/guides).
- [*Spring Guides*](https://spring.io/guides)

Очень простые и наглядные пошаговые уроки (на английском) разных возможностей проектов Spring, с возможностью сразу скачать результат и проверить на своем компьютере. Наиболее актуальные туториалы по Spring, которые есть в интернете, так как постоянно обновляются сообществом. Для более детального изучения - смотрите [официальную документацию](https://spring.io/projects).

- *Spring в действии*. Крейг Уоллс

  Несмотря на то, что в книге описана уже немолодая 3-я версия Spring, книга стоит ознакомления, так как очень просто и подробно знакомит читателя с фреймворком.
- *Spring 5 для профессионалов*. Юлиана Козмина, Роб Харроп, Крис Шефер,
  Кларенс Хо

  Многолетний бестселлер, считающийся наиболее исчерпывающим и авторитетным руководством по Spring.
- *Pro Spring Integration*. Dr. Mark Lui, Mario Gray, Andy Chan and Josh Long (англ.)

Pro Spring Integration - это авторитетная книга от экспертов, которая проведет вас через обширный мир интеграции корпоративных приложений (EAI) и применения инфраструктуры Spring Integration для решения проблем интеграции.

- *Pro Spring 5, 5th Edition (2017)* Iuliana Cosmina, Rob Harrop, Chris Schaefer, Clarence Ho (англ.)

С помощью этой книги вы сможете изучить основы Spring, фреймворка для Java-платформы, а также EJB и Hibernate. Вы узнаете, как использовать Spring для создания различных частей Java-приложения: транзакций, веб и много другого. Пример приложения, описанного в книге, позволит применить на практике технологии и методы Spring и увидеть, как они работают вместе. Книга подойдет опытным разработчикам на Java.

- *Learn Microservices with Spring Boot: A Practical Approach to RESTful Services using RabbitMQ, Eureka, Ribbon, Zuul and Cucumber* Moises Macero (англ.)

Создайте архитектуру микросервисов с помощью Spring Boot, превратив приложение из небольшого монолита в управляемую событиями архитектуру, состоящую из нескольких служб. Эта книга следует поэтапному подходу к обучению микросервисной структуре, разработке через тестирование, Eureka, Ribbon, Zuul и сквозным тестам с Cucumber.

---

## Hibernate

- *Beginning Hibernate*. Joseph B. Ottinger, Dave Minter, Jeff Linwood

  Несмотря на то, что в названии книги стандарт JPA не упоминается, бóльшая часть книги посвящена именно его реализации в Hibernate.
- *Java Persistence with Hibernate*. C. Bauer, G. King, G. Gregory

  Исчерпывающее описание Hibernate и Java Persistence.
- *High-Performance Java Persistence book*. Vlad Mihalcea.

Данная книга подробно рассказывает о работе с Hibernate ORM, а так же оптимизации кода для лучшей производительности. Данная книга была одобрена на [официальном аккаунте Java](https://twitter.com/java/status/1080147137764171777?s=20), а так же автор книги является [одним из разработчиков Hibernate](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-orm/graphs/contributors). Также, автор книги активно отвечает на вопросы пользователей в https://stackoverflow.com

---

## Swing

- *SWING: Эффективные пользовательские интерфейсы*. Иван Портянкин.
- *Swing. A Beginner's Guide*. Sсhildt H.

  Русский перевод: *Swing. Руководство для начинающих*. Шилдт Г.
- *Swing Hacks. Tips and Tools for Killer GUIs*. Joshua Marinacci, Chris Adamson.

---

## JavaFX

- *JavaFX 2.0 Разработка RIA-приложений*. Тимур Машнин.

  В ней есть вся нужная информация относительно компонентов и оформления их с помощью fxcss, работы с анимацией, воспроизведения видео и аудио, и конечно относительно работы с FXML.
- *Learn JavaFX 8*. Kishori Sharan.

  Учебник на английском, в нем подробно описываются все основные элементы JavaFX, особенности их поведения и взаимодействия, описываются наблюдаемые свойства и связывания (properties and bindings), и другие полезные возможности, как вывод на печать и подробное описание обработки событий.
- [**Руководство по JavaFX**](https://metanit.com/java/javafx/) на metanit.com

---

## Справочники

- *Java 8 Pocket Guide*. Robert Liguori.

  Русский перевод: *Java 8. Карманный справочник.* Роберт Лигуори.

  Отличный справочник, с помощью которого можно моментально найти ответы на вопросы по стандартной библиотеке Java, лямбда-выражениям и т. д.

---

## Онлайн-ресурсы

- Российская [Java User Group](http://jug.ru). В архиве очень много докладов по Java, Spring и так далее. Доклады в основном на русском, рассчитаны на опытных разработчиков.
- [Awesome Java](https://github.com/akullpp/awesome-java) - поддерживаемый список лучших библиотек, фреймворков и приложений в мире Java.
- [Useful java links](https://github.com/Vedenin/useful-java-links) - альтернативный список лучших библиотек, фреймворков и приложений в мире Java. Есть [русская версия](https://github.com/Vedenin/useful-java-links/tree/master/link-rus).
- [Useful java links (video)](https://github.com/Vedenin/useful-java-links/tree/master/link-rus#ix-%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE-java) - поддерживаемый список русскоязычных видео с докладов и конференций по категориям.
- [baeldung.com](http://baeldung.com/) - На данном сайте представлено огромное множество статей, уроков по разработке приложения на Spring. Уроки на сайте идут вместе с кодом, который вы найдете в Github в конце каждой статьи. Так же, в уроках представлены разные решения одной и той же проблемы, что не сомнено делает данным сайт полезным как для новичков, так и для опытных программистов.
- [vladmihalcea](https://vladmihalcea.com/) - Данный сайт является официальным сайтом одного из разработчиков Hibernate - Vlad Mihalcea. На данном сайте вы найдете множество бесплатных уроков по Hibernate. А так же SQL и Spring
- [Thorben Janssen](https://thorben-janssen.com/) - эксперт по JPA и Hibernate. Ведет текстовый и видеоблог.
- [Мысли о Java](https://thoughts-on-java.org/) - На данном ресурсе, как и на ресурсе выше вы найдете множество статей и уроков связанных с Hibernate и JPA. Автор сайта имеет многолетний опыт работы с Hibernate. Более десяти лет назад он использовал один из первых релизов Hibernate для реализации уровня персистентности корпоративных приложений.

Comment: Думаю будет полезен : [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/13urRX1KazY-wCg0161FX5oKJ6OFUFmCoj-2jsR_tjJk/pub)