# Разбить строку в массив

Tags: java, массивы, строки

После парса, приходит строка типа: `"Москва-Ярославль 04 ясно понятно"`.
Как ее преобразовать в массив типа :`co[]{"Москва-Ярославль", "04", "ясно", "понятно"}` 
причем вот это `co[]` должно динамически изменять имя, так как придет, скажем,  таких строк, и должно получиться 5 таких массивов с разными именами..)

Comment: Что именно парсится? Каким образом будут приходить эти строки? Последовательно в разных ответах сервера или все вместе в одном ответе?

Comment: @m-g-demin , парсится таблица с помощью jsoup, приходит все в одном ответе

Comment: а андроид при чем тут?

Comment: @Nofate, потому что это часть моей программы, которую я под андроид пишу

Comment: По секрету скажу: что с андроидом, что без него  - задача на java решается одинаково. Перед написанием программ под Android настоятельно рекомендую осилить основы языка: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/

Comment: @Nofate, основы я более-менее знаю, а совершенствуюсь уже в процессе. Так интереснее

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если есть гарантия что в элементах массива отсутствуют пробелы, то очевидное решение

```
строка_которая_пришла.split(" ")
```

Comment: всмысле отсутствуют?

Comment: Он имеет ввиду то, что split(" ") разбивает по пробелам. И если написать "Иван Петров" то будет два отдельных элемента в массиве. Кстати, полная запись будет примерно такая String[] имяПеременной = строка_которая_пришла.split(" ");  т.е. размер массива указывать не нужно

Comment: Исходя из пример текста, вполне может оказаться `"Нижний Тагил-Санкт-Петербург"`.