# Java, конструкторы и рандом

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Есть такой код:

```
public class Pen {

    public Pen() { //конструктор
        Random rand = new Random();
        int i = rand.nextInt(4);
        switch(i) {
            case 0:name=("Parker Urban");break;
            case 1:name=("Parker Jotter");break;
            case 2:name=("Parker IM");break;
            case 3:name=("Parker Insignia");break;
        }
    }

    public void setInfo() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int k = random.nextInt(4);
        switch(k) {
            case 0:System.out.println(name);break;
            case 1:System.out.println(name);break;
            case 2:System.out.println(name);break;
            case 3:System.out.println(name);break;
        }
    }
}
```

Очевидно, что по нажатию на кнопку нужно, чтобы писалось одно из именований ручки. Но, оно выбирается только 1 раз (например, Parker IM) и в дальнейшем, сколько раз на кнопку не жми - название ручки остается таким же.
Я понимаю, что код - костыль, и должно быть написано не так, но что именно ???
Помогите, пожалуйста, решить загадку.

Comment: Покажите какой код вызвается при нажатии на кнопку?

Comment: Ээээ... А чем отличаются случаи в `setInfo`?

Comment: каков смысл кода в `setInfo()` ?

Comment: При вызове метода в консоль должно выводиться название ручки.

Comment: вы понимаете, что рандом в `setInfo()` не делает ничего?

Comment: Просто выводите `System.out.println(name)`

Comment: и да, хотелось бы увидеть код обработчика кнопки

Comment: в коде обработчика кнопки идет просто вызов метода.

если оставить 1 "System.out.println(name)" - тогда оно просто выбирает одно из 4 имён, и если выпавшее не совпадает с начальным - оно не пишет ничего.

Comment: Какого? Почему из вас нужно вытягивать информацию щипцами? Вы правда хотите помощи?

Comment: setInfo()
мне это показалось очевидным,
он единственный в предоставленном коде

Comment: @Дмитрий вы понимаете что название ручки вы задаете только один раз в конструкторе и в одну единственную переменную, в дальнейшем, сколько раз не вызывай метод 'setInfo', название ручки не изменится и выведется то, которое было заданно в конструкторе ?

Comment: Понимаю.
Тогда, в теории, я могу создать под каждый кейс отдельную переменную, и создать в setInfo() свитч, который в зависимости от того, какая переменная выпала - будет писать в консоль?
Хотя, кажется я перепутал, и выводиться будет всё так же одно имя..

Answer (score 2):

Значение `name` устанавливается у Вас в конструкторе, потом, когда вызывается метод  `setInfo()` он просто выводит `name` на экран. Независимо от сгенерированного числа в `setInfo()`, значение `name` одинаково, т.к. не видно нигде где `name` перезаписывается.

```
class Pen {

   String[] array; 
   Random random;        

   public Pen() {

       random = new Random();

       array = new string[4];
       array[0] = "Parker Urban";
       array[1] = "Parker Jotter";
       array[2] = "Parker IM";
       array[3] = "Parker Insignia";
   }


   public void setInfo() {

       System.out.println(array[random.nextInt(4)]);

    }
}
```

Comment: Почему это рандом генерирует одниковые числа?

Comment: > Но, оно выбирается только 1 раз (например, Parker IM) и в дальнейшем, сколько раз на кнопку не жми - название ручки остается таким же.

Comment: random.nextInt() возвращает разные числа в независимости от инициализации.

Comment: Возможно, здесь я точно утверждать не могу. Но проблема генерация одинаковых чисел не нова.

Comment: Это всё я в общем-то понимаю, но как проблему-то решить?

Comment: @Дмитрий дебажить конечно же!! умеешь ? берёшь System.out.println() и выводишь свои недо-рандомные переменные после генерации. и смотришь почему, что и как вылезло.

Comment: Понятия не имею как это

Comment: @Дмитрий, тогда надо взять учебники и немного их осилить: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634

Comment: это немного затянется

Comment: @Дмитрий затянется? ну конечно затянется! а ты думал как люди Яву учат? с наскока ? с таким отношением можно стать только ПОГРОМ'истом.

Comment: пусть пока я буду ПОГРОМ'истом, но эту проблему решить надо сейчас, а не через пару месяцов