# Задачки по Java OOP

Tags: java, ооп

Посоветуйте хорошую книгу по Java, где огромное количество задач по ООП. Желательно на русском.

Comment: Есть некое правило сайта, не задавать вопросов которые предусматривают субъективные ответы.

Comment: Меня интересуют именно задачи по ООП

Comment: [Книги по Java и другая литература](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416634/178576)

Comment: Нет такой книги. Немного подходят под ваши критерии "Head First Java" и "Технология разработки программного обеспечения" Брауде. Попробуйте лучше поискать хорошую книгу по объектно-ориентированному анализу и дизайну.