# Хорошая книга по Java

Tags: java, веб-программирование, android

Друзья, в моей компании закрылся последний .NET проект, мне рекомендуют перейти на проекты Java (Андроид или WEB). Дают 3 месяца на самоподготовку. Я работал только с .NET платформой, Java не интересовался.

Пожалуйста подскажите очень толковую книгу, желательно на английском Информации по Java так много, и не понять с чего начать.

Comment: [Книги по Java и другая литература](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/Книги-по-java-и-другая-литература)

Comment: @AlexKrass, очевидно следующим вопросом будет -- "и что из этого вы предлагаете именно мне?"

Comment: @avp, ну если бы у меня была такая задача: быстро пролистать одну книгу для начинающих, Thinking in Java + Effective Java, JavaFX и добить справочником/документацией. Хотя я не сильно знаком с java, могу ошибиться в эффективности.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Эккель "Философия Java"
2. Гонсалес "Java EE"
3. Если нужен android то Майер "Android 4. Программирование приложений"

Думаю хватит :)

Comment: Огромное спасибо !