# locationManager: вылетает исключение FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: java, android

Проблема следующая: при переходе выполнения к строке с locationManager вылетает исключение FATAL EXCEPTION: main.

Подробнее:
В MainActivity вызываю конструктор GPSTracker(MainActivityCW.this), после чего, при наличии не закоментированного try в классе GPSTracker, получаю исключение FATAL EXCEPTION: main. Соответственно tracker.canGetLocation() в MainActivityCW получает значение false (значение по умолчанию).
Пробовал убирать, перемещать строку с locationManager, но везде именно на ней ошибка.

Код GPSTracker:

```
import...

public class GPSTracker implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
public boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // 10 meters
// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    Log.i("GPS", "CONSTRUCTOR");
    getLocation();
}

// Function to get the user's current location
public Location getLocation() {
    Log.i("GPS", "getLocation method");
    //try {
        Log.i("GPS", "try 1");

        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Log.i("GPS", "try 2");

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Log.i("GPS", "isGPSEnabled =" + isGPSEnabled);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        Log.i("GPS", "isNetworkEnabled =" + isNetworkEnabled);

        if (isGPSEnabled == false && isNetworkEnabled == false) {
            // no network provider is enabled
            Log.i("GPS","no network provider is enabled");
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                location=null;
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.i("GPS", "Network Enabled!");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                location=null;
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    //} catch (Exception e) {
    //    Log.i("GPS", "getLocation EXCEPTION");
    //    e.printStackTrace();
    //}
    return location;
}

//Stop using GPS listener Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}


// Function to get latitude
public double getLatitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }
    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

// Function to get longitude
public double getLongitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

// Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    Log.i("GPS","canGetLocation method");
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

// Function to show settings alert dialog On pressing Settings button will launch Settings Options
public void showSettingsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}
}
```

Код MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivityCW extends Activity {

TextView currentCoordinates;

GPSTracker tracker = new GPSTracker(MainActivityCW.this);
double latitude;
double longitude;

Timer timer = new Timer();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    currentCoordinates = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentCoordinates);

    final long UPD_START_DELAY = 0; // 1 сек = 1000 мс
    final long UPD_PERIOD = 5000; // 1 сек = 1000 мс

    timer.schedule(new UpdateCoordinates(), UPD_START_DELAY, UPD_PERIOD);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

public void goToSettings(View v) {
    Intent relationMainToSettings = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
    startActivity(relationMainToSettings);
}

class UpdateCoordinates extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        MainActivityCW.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                        latitude = tracker.getLatitude();
                        longitude = tracker.getLongitude();
                        currentCoordinates.setText("Lat: " + Double.toString(latitude) + " Lon: "
                                + Double.toString(longitude));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.fillInStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        });

    }
}
}
```

Ошибка:

```
11-20 01:25:01.373    9258-9258/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{ua.repikserj.CarpatianWays/ua.repikserj.CarpatianWays.MainActivityCW}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2001)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:965)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:732)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
        at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4033)
        at ua.repikserj.CarpatianWays.GPSTracker.getLocation(GPSTracker.java:51)
        at ua.repikserj.CarpatianWays.GPSTracker.<init>(GPSTracker.java:42)
        at ua.repikserj.CarpatianWays.MainActivityCW.<init>(MainActivityCW.java:17)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:965) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:732) at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @zRrr, а вы перенесите коммент в ответ)

Comment: Коммент я перенес. А есть приличные каноничные примеры работы с геолокацией? Этот ужасен сам по себе, и требует доводки под Marshmallow, но распространен повсеместно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Текст исключения `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()` говорит о том, что код где-то вызывает `Activity.getSystemService` до вызова `onCreate`, т.е. до завершения инициализации Activity.

Вызов происходит в `GPSTracker.getLocation`, который вызывается в конструкторе `GPSTracker` (вызов неприватных нефинальных методов в конструкторе - не лучшая идея), который вызывается при инициализации поля `MainActivityCW.tracker` (передавать кому-то `this` до завершения работы конструктора совсем не стоит).

Чтобы исключение ушло, перенесите создание экземпляра `GPSTracker` в `MainActivityCW.onCreate`:

```
GPSTracker tracker;
double latitude;
double longitude;

...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    currentCoordinates = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentCoordinates);

    tracker = new GPSTracker(this);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, помогло. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, где можно почитать про такие нюансы, как "вызов неприватных нефинальных методов в конструкторе - не лучшая идея".

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/ - список литературы по Java. Начать стоит с Effective Java. Про переопределяемые методы в конструкторах, наверное, пишут в книгах по ООП.