# Изучение Java и версии

Tags: java

Решил начать изучение Java. В программировании полный ноль, ну то есть вообще. Чтобы поняли, не понимаю различие между классом, методом, функцией и командой.

По другим ответам нашел книжку как я понял для таких чайников как я: К. Сьерра, Б. Бейтс - Изучаем Java.
Но там написано что она написана под реалии Java5, хотя насколько я понял, актуальной версией языка является Java8?
Есть ли смысл начинать обучаться по этой книге? Или это уже устаревшее? Насколько версии языка различаются между собой?

Answer (score 2):

Да, смысл есть. Даже если изучите Java5, не составит труда быстро доучить Java8. Хоть Java5 устарела, но на сегодняшний день, до сих пор работают проекты и на Java 6.

Книги которые советую к прочтению (список составлялся когда-то для себя):

1   «Философию Java» Брюса Эккеля
2    Java Thread Programming by Paul Hyde - @Не смотрите на то, что книга 1998 года.
3   Concurrent Programming In Java by Doug Lea. - @настоятельно рекомендую вам познакомиться
4   «Concurrency In Practice», написанная Brian Goetz.
5   Art Of Multiprocessor Programming by Maurice Herlihy
6   Java Generics and Collections - @поможет вам заодно и разобраться с Generics.
7   Java Collections by John Zhukovski
8    Java I/O by Elliotte Rusty 
9    Java Reflection In Action by Ira R. Forman - @Приготовьтесь вспомнить/выучить UML для полного понимания.
10   JDBC API Tutorial and Reference by Maydene Fisher
11  «Лямбда-выражения в Java 8» Ричарда Уорбэртона
12   «Java SE8. Вводный курс» (она же Java 8 для нетерпеливых) Хортсманна.
13  «Чистый код» Роберта Мартина - @является его лучшей книгой на данный момент
14  «Совершенный Код» Стива Макконнелла. - @Куда более фундаментальная работа

Ну а начать пожалуй стоит с  Java. Библиотека профессионала, том 1. Основы (Кей С. Хорстманн, Гари Корнелл) и том 2

Answer (score 2):

Смысл есть, все базовые вещи появились как раз в Java 5.

Краткое описание отличия версий можно посмотреть в [вики](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history).

В Java хорошая обратная совместимость, т.е. то, что вы скомпилируте под старой версией JDK, с большой долей вероятности запустится под новой, но не наоборот.

Java 8 является последней версией JDK, но [более популярной](https://plumbr.eu/blog/java/java-version-statistics-2015-edition) до сих пор является Java 7. Кроме того, это последняя версия, которую можно поставить на Windows XP. Да-да, не смейтесь, энтерпрайз это не домашние персоналки, многие конторы еще не скоро с нее слезут. Java 7 будет актуальна еще очень долго.

Так что, я бы посоветовал устанавливать [JDK 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) (именно Oracle, а не OpenJDK), и все-таки взять книжку поновее. Того же Хостмана. А когда подучите язык уже смотреть в сторону Java 8 c ее фишками из функционального программирования.

Ну а список литературы [посмотреть тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416635/197447).