# Как из другого класса обратиться к элементам формы java

Tags: java, swing

Есть базовый класс, а есть другой класс не унаследованный от базового.

Так сложилось что нужно значение label изменить из другого класса (хотя label декларирован в базовом)

Пытался создать объект базового в в другом классе, но это ничего не давало

Код который устанавливает значения такой `jLabel.setText("something");`

Comment: сделать `jlabel` глобальным?

Comment: Можно с базового класса передать ссылку на самого себя в другой класс!

Comment: можно пример???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы опять почему-то не приводите код. Будем гадать.

> базовый класс
>   label декларирован в базовом

Допустим:

```
public class Foo {
    private JLabel jlabel;

    // ... конструкторы, другие методы

    public updateLabel(String text) {
        jLabel.setText(updateLabel);
    }
}
```

> есть другой класс не унаследованный от базового
>   нужно значение label изменить из другого класса

Он должен иметь ссылку на экземпляр "базового класса". Она может быть передана в конструктор или непосредственно в метод, в котором вы хотите обновить label.

```
public class Bar {
    private Foo foo;

    public Bar(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    // метод, в котором вы делаете вызов 
    public void baz() {
        // ... какой-то код ...
        foo.updateLabel("something"); // обращаемся к методу в Foo, чтобы обновить label
        // ... какой-то код ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Как мне сделать у объекта jLabel1 свой метод?
У меня есть в коде такая строка `jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();`
Как я понимаю JLabel - это совсем другой класс и от него нужно создать класс наследник и запихать туда свой метод?!

Comment: нет. метод нужно добавить в класс, в котором строка `jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();`

Comment: Ну так я писал примерно ранее что-то эдакое: `public void changeLabel1(String text){jLabel1.setText(text);}` Но как обратиться не знаю, это ведь не статический метод я же не могу написать: `changeLabel1("Hello")`?

Comment: ну так создайте объект класса, в котором написан этот метод.

Comment: Типо так: `final Frame frame = new Frame();` `frame.changeLabel1("Hello");`
Если я объявлю frame (Frame - это главный класс) то появляется неизвестная ошибка

Comment: `public static void main(String args[]){
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }`
Это у меня инициализирующая функция. Как обратиться к объекту Frame? Или как сделать на него ссылку?

Comment: `Frame frame = new Frame(); frame.setVisible(true);` Может быть вам стоит с основ языка начать?

Comment: я так писал, но я не мог обратиться к frame из другого метода (потому что эта переменная только для класса main), а если объявить свойство, то он будет говорить что в статическом методе нельзя обращаться к объектам

Comment: Передайте объект frame в другой метод параметром.

Comment: Например? а то я уже совсем запутался...

Comment: например, `myMethod(frame)`. тогда внутри метода `myMethod` можно будет обратиться к `frame`

Comment: Что-то типо такого? В контексте main:`frame.getFrame(frame);`
Теперь объявляем метод: `public void getFrame(Frame frame)
{frame_link = frame;}`
Где-то объявляем свойство: `public Frame frame_link;`
Потом обращаемся к методу для лейбла: `frame_link.changeLabel1("Hello");`

Comment: может быть, мне трудно гадать по обрывкам кода.

Comment: по крайней мере это заработало, спасибо за советы, хотелось бы спросить какую литературу почитать по java (интересует программирование оконных приложений) да и вообщем что посоветуете как эксперт? Просто я в основном сейчас почитывю интернет статьи ибо здоровые книги в 1к страниц читать утомительно и эффект не особо сильный

Comment: У нас же есть хороший список - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634

Comment: Если толстые книги плохо идут попробуйте *Head First Java* (*Изучаем Java*. Кэти Сиерра, Берт Бейтс.)

Comment: заинтересовала ваша книжка!!! буду читать!