# Java объектно ориентированное программирование

Tags: java

Посоветуйте хорошую книгу по объектно ориентированносу программированию в *Java*. В интернете порылся, но по отзывам ничего толкового не нашел - книги или плохие, или с кучей воды, или ооп рассматривается лишь частично.

Comment: Ну а первую из среднего уровня в ответе [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/) смотрели?..

Comment: Попробуйте в java попрограммировать без объектов. И никакие книжки не нужны

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да. Но там обобщенные книги. Вообще есть книги чисто по ООП?

Comment: Могу посоветовать по объектно-ориентированному анализу почитать Гради Буча. Например, вот это http://goo.gl/xyTP2o

Comment: @bukashka101 Сколько людей - столько мнений. Одному книга нравится, другой-же скажет плохая. Берите и читайте и делайте свои выводы, а там и понимание прибудет.

Comment: Эккель, Философия Java - канон