# Где можно побольше узнать о сборке java-проектов?

Tags: java, сборка

С самого начала знакомства с java использовал IDE Idea, чуть позже попробовал такие сборщики как Maven и Gradle(им сейчас и пользуюсь).Однако, не смотря на все эти удобства хочется лучше понять процессы, которые эти инструменты делают за меня. Поделитесь пожалуйста наводками на полезные уроки про сборке проектов. Из хорошего я нашел [такой урок](http://www.skipy.ru/philosophy/beginning.html). В целом расписано здорово, но хотелось бы по этой теме еще что-нибудь почитать и ознакомиться со сборкой в ос Windows.Заранее спасибо

Comment: Что именно вас интересует? про сборку jar руками обязательно пишут  в любом [учебнике](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416634/1984), про жизненный цикл maven - лучше всего какой-нибудь Maven in Action,

Comment: речь не о сборщиках, а как руками от и до собрать из написанных классов проект и привести его к такому виду,чтобы обычный человек мог двойным щелчком его запустить. спасибо за ссылку,ознакомлюсь