# Java. Создание объекта. Советы про использование String

Tags: java

Я недавно начал изучать Java и у меня возникло несколько вопросов.

1. Мне непонятно почему в Java  нет простого механизма (метода) ввода\ вывода  чего либо. То есть когда в Pascal - это `write\read` или Python - `print\input`. В Java есть стандартное средство вывода - `System.out.println`, но ввод нужно реализовывать через импорт `Scanner`.
   Подскажите это я чего-то не понимаю или реально в таком мощном языке
   нету таких базовых методов?
   Также как я понял `Scanner` подходит лишь для текста, а что  если мне нужно вводить числа? Что использовать? Можно полностью написать как это будет выглядеть.
2. Объясните пожалуйста, что значат аргументы в этой команде.

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args)
   ```
3. Можно объясните принцип создание экземпляра класса. Например:

   ```
   String variable = new String ("Text");
   ```

   Почему почему дважды вызывается класс `String` в начале и при создании?
   Я понимаю, что можно просто смирится и все, но мне не понятно зачем это действие, есть для этого объяснение или это сделано просто так?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Java - объектно-ориентированный язык в отличие от Паскаля, и его богатая система классов ввода-вывода, базирующаяся на потоках (streams), позволяет использовать одни и те же механизмы для любых ситуаций: работа с консолью, работа с файлами, работа с сетью, работа с архивами.

   Раз речь зашла про класс `Scanner` - обратимся к [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

   Класс предоставляет кучу методов для разных ситуаций:

   - `String next(String pattern)` - вернет строку, если она соответствует шаблону;
   - `boolean nextBoolean()` - вернет значение булева типа;
   - `int nextInt()` - вернет целочисленное значение;
   - `float nextFloat()` - вернет значение с плавающей точкой типа `float`.

   Это не все, то умеет `Scanner`, но теперь вы знаете, где искать.

---

2. Это не команда. Это объявление публичного (`public` - доступного всем) статического (`static` - доступного без создания экземпляра класса)  метода `main`, который принимает массив строк (`String[] args`) и ничего не возвращает (`void`).

   Согласно спецификации, метод с такой сигнатурой является точкой входа в вашу программу. То есть, при запуске в командной строке `java MyClass` выполнение программы начнется с этого метода в классе `MyClass`. В качестве массива `args` будут переданы аргументы из командной строки. Например, при запуске `java MyClass foo bar` массив `args` будет иметь значение `["foo", "bar"]`.

---

3. > почему дважды вызывается Класс String в начале и при создании
   >
   > ```
   > String variable = new String ("Text");
   > ```

   Класс не "вызывается", класс нельзя "вызвать". В данном случае происходит три действия:

   - Объявляется переменная `variable` типа `String`.
   - Создается новый экземпляр типа `String` через конструктор с одним аргументом `"Text"`.
   - Переменной `variable` присваивается ссылка на созданный объект.

   В случае со строками это можно было сократить до вида:

   ```
   String variable = "Text";
   ```

PS. Крайне рекомендую начать изучение Java, вооружившись одним из учебников для начинающих, там есть ответы на подобные вопросы: [Книги по Java и другая литература](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634)

---

PPS. В следующий раз, пожалуйста, соблюдайте правила и задавайте по одному вопросу за раз.

Comment: Все спасибо за отзывчивость. Теперь я понял, почему нужно 2 раза String.
Я читал про ООП, общие принципы мне понятны. Но честно говоря в книгах про Java очень запутанно объясняют, а я не нашел книги нормальной для новичков. Извините что нарушил правила с большим количеством вопросов.

Comment: @AlexKing, попробуйте *Кэти Сиерра, Берт Бейтс - Изучаем Java (Head First Java)*. Там все предельно подробно и просто разжевывается.

Answer (score 3):

1. В java все вводы/выводы основаны на потоках и их реализациях для консоли, файла и т.д. Чтение/запись в консоль - частный случай работы с потоками. Scanner - класс, имеющий в себе реализацию чтения чего-либо из потока. Но из консоли читать не только с его помощью можно.
2. Аргументы String[] args - это те параметры, которые будут переданы в метод при вызове его из коммандной строки. Т.е. если будет вызов вида
   `java MyClass param1 param2`, то args - это строковый массив, содержащий строки param1 и param2. Если вызов происходит без параметров, этот массив будет пустым.
3. Первый  String - указание типа объявляемой далее переменной variable. В java имеет место статическая типизация, в отличие от Python. И в отличие от паскаля, где сначала объявляются все переменные, а затем происходит их использование, в java возможно объявление переменных в любом месте, главное чтобы до их непосредственного использования. Второй String - это вызов конструктора класса String с передачей ему параметра. В результате получаем объект класса String, который присваивается переменной variable.

Answer (score 3):

1 простых методов типа write\read в Java нет.
Ввод чисел можно сделать так:

```
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
String st=scanner.nextLine();
int i=Integer.parseInt(st);
```

2 это аргументы командной строки с которыми запускается ваше приложение.

3 первое слово String задает тип переменной variable, new String ("Text") создает новый объект String.
Вообще можно сразу и не инициализировать variable:

```
String variable;
/...какой-то код.../
variable=new String("text");
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Проблема с выводом не ясна. Чтобы что-то вывести в консоль просто пишите

   ```
   System.out.println(ТУТ_ЧТО_ТО);
   ```

   В качестве аргумента (ТУТ_ЧТО_ТО) можно подставить или примитив или объект. В последнем случае он будет автоматически преобразован с строку и выведен в консоль.
2. В метод `main` передаётся массив строк, являющихся параметрами для запуска программы. Например, запуская через командную строку, вы можете передать что-то и получить это в качестве аргкумента метода `main`.
3. Класс не вызывается дважды. Сначала объявляется его тип, указывается имя переменной-ссылки, после чего создаётся объект и присваивается этой переменной-ссылке. Сделано так, а не иначе т.к. [java](/questions/tagged/java) - язык со строгой типизацией.
   Например в [php](/questions/tagged/php) тип переменной не указывают и вы можете всё что угодно ей присвоить. И никакой компилятор вас не одёрнет, если вы попытаетесь сложить число `1.(3)` со строкой `"Вася"`.

Comment: Автору нужно прочитать про ООП в книге по Java, хотя бы буквально пару страниц