# Аннотация в Java EE

Tags: java, java-ee, аннотации

Всем привет. Хотел узнать у знающих, что такое аннотации, и зачем они нужны. 
До того как начал изучать Java EE у меня было представление, что я знаю, что это такое. Но как дошел до Java EE, увидел, что они применяются везде особенно в JAX-RS и при написании веб сервисов.

Зашел в документацию прочитать про `@Context` и посмотреть что там внутри. Вот то, что увидел, если кто сможет объяснить синтаксис и саму логику данного кода буду признателен. Если есть ссылки на объяснение буду рад почитать.

```
 @Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
 @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
 @Documented
 public @interface Context {
 }
```

Comment: вот почитайте http://www.seostella.com/ru/article/2012/05/19/annotacii-v-java-vvedenie.html

Comment: Прочитал вашу статью.. Абсолютно нечем не помогло.

Comment: Не помогло, так не помогло. Что ж, и такое бывает. А статья кстати не моя. Не пишу я статей.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это просто объявление аннотации без какой-либо логики. Как объявить аннотацию, рассказывается в [любом учебнике по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416634/1984).

По-порядку:

```
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
```

Аннотация [`@Target`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Target.html), объявляет элементы исходного кода, к которым можно применить создаваемую аннотацию. В данном случае это: параметры методов ([`ElementType.PARAMETER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html)), сами методы ([`ElementType.METHOD`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html)) и поля классов ([`ElementType.FIELD`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html)).

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
```

Аннотация [`@Retention`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Retention.html), говорит компилятору, как долго нужно хранить аннотацию в коде. Политика [`RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html) заставляет компилятор сохранить аннотации в `.class`-файлах и делает их доступными во время выполнения программы через рефлексию.

```
@Documented
```

Аннотация [`@Documented`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Documented.html) включает создаваемую аннотацию в список элементов исходного кода, для которых генерируется документация (при использовании инструментов генерации документации).

```
public @interface Context { }
```

Это, собственно, непосредственно объявление новой аннотации `@Context`.

---

Сами по себе аннотации - просто маркеры, никакой работы они не выполняют.

Что касается логики ("магии") аннотаций то обычно это работает так: есть какой-то класс, отвечающий за инициализацию, он пробегает при помощи рефлексии по классам в определенном пакете и ищет какую-то аннотацию. Если находит - экземпляры этого класса подвергаются какой-либо обработке, например полям классов задаются некоторые значения.

В случае с JAX-RS "магией" занимается поставщик реализации (напр. CXF, Jersey, RESTEasy). Где-то в его недрах есть класс, который анализирует аннотации, которыми вы украсили ваши ресурсы и выполняет действия в соответствии со спецификацией JAX-RS. Например, составляет карту соответствий URL-ов конкретным методам, на основе аннотаций `@Path` и `@GET`/`@PUT`/`@POST`/`@DELETE`.

Comment: Nofate - спасибо за ответ!!

Comment: Nofate  Хотел спросить тебя по поводу @Context : 
Чем отличается от "@QueryParam" "@PathParam" ?  
3.5. Rules of Injection по ссылке: 
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e2789
Не могу понять разницу между ними по примерам в документации по ссылке..

Comment: @Maks.Burkov, лучше задайте отдельный вопрос - я поясню с примером.

Comment: @Nofate Также советую почитать про annotation processing http://www.javatronic.fr/articles/2014/10/08/how_does_annotation_processing_work_in_java.html. Компиляцию java классов в байт код основываясь на аннотациях (метапрограммирование ) используя https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html

Comment: @DenisVabishchevich мне? зачем? Если вы хотите дополнить информацию - опубликуйте полноценный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Пример на основе [этой статьи](https://habrahabr.ru/post/139736/):

1) Создаем новый класс-аннотацию:

```
@Target(value= ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(value= RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ControlledObject {
    String name();
}
```

2) Используем эту аннотацию, т.е. аннотируем класс:

```
@ControlledObject(name="biscuits")
public class Cookies {
...
}
```

3) Как работает аннотация: где-то в коде мы проверяем, аннотирован ли наш класс `Cookies` этой аннотацией, `ControlledObject`. Если да, то выполняются одни действия, если нет - другие:

```
Class cl = Class.forName("Cookies");
if(!cl.isAnnotationPresent(ControlledObject.class)){
...
}
else {
...
}
```