# Сервлеты и многопоточность

Tags: java, java-ee

Вопрос по данному коду :

1.Насколько я знаю Servlet Container отвечает за потокобезопасность сервлетов.

2.Но сушествует вариант что несмотря на это может возникнуть проблема с потокобезопасностью как например в данном коде.

Мой вопрос заключается в том: 
почему при данном коде переменная counter считается не потокобезопасной ?

```
package threadSafety;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.math.*;
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet
{
//A variable that is NOT thread-safe!
private int counter = 0;
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
throws ServletException, IOException
{
doPost(req, resp);
}
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
throws ServletException, IOException
{
resp.getWriter().println("<HTML><BODY>");
resp.getWriter().println(this + ": <br>");
for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
{
  resp.getWriter().println("Counter = " + counter + "<BR>");
  try
  {
    Thread.currentThread().sleep((long) Math.random() * 1000);
    counter++;
  }
  catch (InterruptedException exc) { }
}
resp.getWriter().println("</BODY></HTML>");
}
}
```

Comment: контейнер не обеспечивает потокобезопасность

Comment: @Etki - Можеш дать ссылку на нормальный материал по этой теме ?
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072798/java-web-development/write-thread-safe-servlets.html Из написанного тут я понял что да обеспечивает.

Comment: Контейнер отвечает за потокобезопасный _вызов_ методов сервлета, но дальше что происходит внутри этих методов (т.е. в вашем коде) его уже не интересует. Как вы себе вообще представляете, что контейнер будет магически превращать весь ваш потоко-небезопасный код в потокобезопасный?

Comment: Так если контейнер отвечает за потокобезопасный вызов методов сервлета то значит каждый метод сервлета синхронизированный так ? 
Если объявить общую переменную в сервлете то потокобезопасность ее не касается ? 
Ответ @Etki был таким - контейнер не обеспечивает потокобезопасность.. Абсолютно не понятно что происходит. 
Если есть у кого подробное описание процесса - буду рад!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создание собственных потоков в контейнере сервлетов - не очень хорошая практика. Если есть возможность, то лучше перейти к [асинхронной обработки запросов](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets012.htm).

В противном случае, вы сами обязаны отвечать за потокобезопасность, отключение и вообще весь контроль за вашими потоками.

Отвечая на ваши вопросы:

> 1.Насколько я знаю Servlet Container отвечает за потокобезопасность сервлетов.

Для порожденных вами потоков - нет.

> 2.Но сушествует вариант что несмотря на это может возникнуть проблема с потокобезопасностью как например в данном коде.

Так как переменная у вас уровня экземпляра, а контейнер создает на каждый сервлет только один экземпляр его класса(https://java.net/downloads/servlet-spec/Final/servlet-3_1-final.pdf - глава 2, параграф 2.2), то и эта переменная будет общая для всех запросов и соответственно модифицировать ее могут несколько запросов одновременно.

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072798/java-web-development/write-thread-safe-servlets.html 
Пример взят из этой статьи. Посмотри. Там описывается что да.

Comment: @Maks.Burkov, извиняюсь проглядел что переменная не локальная. Сейчас поправлю ответ.

Comment: В таком случае разве нельзя синхронизировать саму переменную ? 
Например поместив ее в синхронизированный метод или использовать volatile ?

Comment: @Maks.Burkov, что бы не быть многословным посоветую вам почитать - Java Concurrency in Practice там про все кроме новинок очень хорошо написано. И гляньте книги вот из этого списка http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634.

Comment: Спасибо посмотрю!