# Литература по Java для работы в сети

Tags: java

Подскажите хорошую литературу, книги для новичка по программированию на Java в сети. Например, "Хорстманн К., Корнелл Г. - Java. Библиотека профессионала" дает только стандартные примеры, как в других книгах. Герберт Шилдт сеть слабо рассматривает. Вообще книги по Java плохо учат программировать, чем по языку С.

Comment: RFC: 793 TRANSMISSION CONTROL PROTOCOL DARPA INTERNET PROGRAM PROTOCOL SPECIFICATION https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-java-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: *Вообще книги по Java плохо учат программировать*, вы какие-то не те книги читаете. Хорстманн - он больше справочник по API, чем учебник.