# Unexpected token switch при использовании в теле класса

Tags: java, switch

Я взял за основу пример из `Android-Universal-Image-Loader`, убрал всё лишние, немножко переделал - и теперь просто хочу повторно использовать галерею в проекте.

Галерея берет фотографии из файла `Constants.java`.

```java
public class Constants{

    private static String[] image1= new String[] {
            // Heavy images
            "https://img1.goodfon.ru/original/1440x900/2/96/art-sono-devushki-shkolnicy.jpg",
            "https://img1.goodfon.ru/original/1440x900/2/96/art-sono-devushki-shkolnicy.jpg",
            "https://img1.goodfon.ru/original/1440x900/2/96/art-sono-devushki-shkolnicy.jpg"
        };

    private static String[] image2= new String[] {
            // Heavy images
            "https://img1.goodfon.ru/original/1440x900/2/96/art-sono-devushki-shkolnicy.jpg",
            "https://img1.goodfon.ru/original/1440x900/2/96/art-sono-devushki-shkolnicy.jpg",
            "https://img1.goodfon.ru/original/1440x900/2/96/art-sono-devushki-shkolnicy.jpg"
    };

    public static String[] IMAGES = Metal;

    private Constants() {}

    public static class Config {
        public static final boolean DEVELOPER_MODE = false;
    }
    
    public static class Extra {
        public static final String FRAGMENT_INDEX = "com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.FRAGMENT_INDEX";
        public static final String IMAGE_POSITION = "com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.IMAGE_POSITION";
    }
}
```

Изначально `public static String[] IMAGES` был присвоен массив ссылок.
И потом это всё вызывалось в другой активности, обрабатывалось и выводилось.
Теперь сделал так, как в коде выше, и хочу в зависимости от того, какая галерея запущена, присваивать `IMAGES` соответствующий массив ссылок.

Например, как-то так:

```java
public static String[] IMAGES;

    public static String iden = "iMetal";

    switch (iden) {
        case "iMetal":
                IMAGES = Metal;
                break;
... 
}
```

Но мне пишет ошибку: `unexpected token switch`.

Переменную `iden` планировал передавать из другой активности при запуске галереи.

Comment: а зачем вы  switch написали вне тела метода? он так не может и это ошибка компиляции. Оберните тогда уж в статический блок: static { switch(iden) {}} если очень хочется

Comment: извиняюсь за тупой вопрос, а где в этом коде тело метода?

Comment: вот именно, его здесь нет. нужно объявить метод чтобы он появился.

Comment: Нигде, там не объявлено ни одного метода. Попробуйте начать с изучения [основ Java](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634).

Comment: Все, всем спасибо! Вставил static все заработало!

Comment: Еще один вопрос, а могу я в этот код передать переменную через Intent или как то еще? Или нужно все таки объявить метод сразу.

Comment: @Skivs новый вопрос вы можете задать с помощью кнопки [Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка "unexpected token switch" возникает из-за того, что код с оператором `switch` находится вне метода или блока кода. В Java инструкции, такие как `switch`, `if`, `else`, `for` и другие, должны находиться в методах, конструкторах или блоках кода, например, в методе `main`, в методах активности или других пользовательских методах.

В вашем случае, чтобы исправить эту ошибку, поместите код с оператором `switch` в метод, например, в метод вашей активности или другой пользовательской функции:

```java
public class Constants {
    public static String[] IMAGES;

    public static void setImages(String iden) {
        switch (iden) {
            case "iMetal":
                IMAGES = image1; // Предполагается, что у вас есть массив image1, который хотите присвоить
                break;
            // Другие варианты для разных идентификаторов
            default:
                IMAGES = null; // Либо установите другой дефолтный массив
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

После этого вы сможете вызвать метод `setImages` из вашей активности или другого места в коде, передавая значение `iden` для установки соответствующего массива в `IMAGES`. Например:

```java
String iden = "iMetal"; // Получите значение идентификатора откуда-то
Constants.setImages(iden); // Вызов метода для установки соответствующего массива
```

Это позволит вам установить массив ссылок в `IMAGES` в зависимости от значения `iden`, которое вы передадите.

---

Если же вам нужно только инициализировать переменную в классе без явного вызова метода, можно поместить блок `switch` в статический блок инициализации класса.
Такой подход позволяет установить значение переменной до любых других операций в классе и обеспечить корректное ее инициализирование при загрузке класса.
Например, вы можете использовать следующий код:

```java
public class Constants {
    public static String[] IMAGES;

    static {
        String iden = "iMetal"; // Предположим, что вы получили значение идентификатора
        switch (iden) {
            case "iMetal":
                IMAGES = image1; // Предполагается, что у вас есть массив image1, который хотите присвоить
                break;
            // Другие варианты для разных идентификаторов
            default:
                IMAGES = null; // Либо установите другой дефолтный массив
                break;
        }
    }
}
```