# Java Web-программирование, литература

Tags: java, spring, jsp, веб-программирование, jsf

Всем привет. В моем арсенале есть лишь книга "Изучаем Java" К.Сьерра и Б.Бейтс из серии head first. Посоветуйте пожалуйста, литературу или статьи на русском для дальнейшего развития (Английский технический понимаю, но не всё). Нашла книгу http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516680.do , но не нашла русский вариант, буду пробовать так (очень понравилась серия head first от  O'Reilly)
Хотелось бы пойти в след.направлениях:
-JSF
-Spring
Спасибо.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-java-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: В JSF ходить не советую.

Comment: Что не так с JSF? Тем более он сейчас по настоянию разработчика стандарта javaee является главной технологией для строительства web-приложений на java. Сложноват конечно, но если освоишь, не так уж страшно. Вообще лучше от и до узучить javascript-фреймвёрк какой-нибудь и забыть и про jsf и про spring вмечте взятые

Answer (score 4):

**Книги**

[Spring 4 для профессионалов Крис Шефер Кларенс Хо](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/33056979/) - Спринг от А до Я

[Sprin MVC Beginners guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1783284870)

[Pivotal Certified Spring Web Application Developer Exam](http://www.apress.com/us/book/9781484208090) - Книга для подготовки к экзамену для получения сертификата Spring web developer

**Open source projects**

После более мение освоения того что выше можно разобраться с [Spring PetClinic](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic) очень хороший пример приложения spring mvc.

Вот еще список spring mvc opensource проектов [Open source projectcs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604655/any-open-source-spring-sample-project-thats-bigger-than-petclinic)

**Русскоязычные стать по Spring MVC**

[spring-projects.ru](http://spring-projects.ru/)

[devcolibri.com/category/spring](http://devcolibri.com/category/spring)

[javastudy.ru/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc/](http://javastudy.ru/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc/)

Comment: Спасибо. А вот еще тогда вопрос:
Я кроме самой явы (и то версии 6.0) ничего толком не знаю. Я сталкивалась и с JSF и с явабинами (пока не понимаю что это) и некоторыми другими фреймворками. Перед тем как углубляться в изучение SPRING фреймворка, нужно ли еще что-то почитать? Я слышала, что лезть в спринг нужно только после понимания того, как вообще делается java web-приложения...

Comment: Spring на то и есть что бы облегчить и автоматизировать рутинную работу. Так что можешь спокойно уго учить. По поводу JSF нечего не могу сказать, не пишу. Выучи просто хорошо Java, освой maven, jdbc, jpa, hibernate. По java8 есть книга `Герберт Шилдт Java 8. Полное руководство`.

Comment: Spring-у может лет 15 назад не было альтернативы. Но теперь javaee  умеет многое не хуже. Ставишь сервер приложений и на этой базе уже можно приступать к разработке, не притягивая левый фреймвёрк, не изучая что-то сверх "стандарта".

Comment: @Sergey на то они и фрейморки что бы ускорить и облегчить разработку. Я не пропагандирую Spring, но как можно молчать если он настолько хорош?)