# как получить доступ к методу вложенного класса java

Tags: java, методы, inner

Создаю `LRUcache`

класс LRU-алгоритма:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class LRUAlgoritm<K, V> implements Cache<K, V> {
    private final LRUStorage storage;//не хочет компилится т.к."The blank final 
                                    //field storage may not have been initialized" 
                                    // помогите как здесь правильно реализовать

    @Override
    public V get(K key) {

        return storage.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {

        return storage.put(key, value);
    }

    private class LRUStorage extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> {
        private final int capacity;

        private LRUStorage(int capacity) {
            this.capacity = capacity;
        }

        protected boolean removedEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> eldest) {
            return size() > capacity;
        }
    }
}
```

интерфейс Cache простой:

```
public interface Cache <K,V>{
    V get (K key);
    V put (K key, V value);
}
```

в классе runner

```
public class Runner {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        LRUAlgoritm<String, String> lruAlgoritm = new LRUAlgoritm<>();
        lruAlgoritm.put("1","1");   
    }
}
```

пытаюсь создать перегрузку кэша и не могу

1. компилятор требует в классе `LRUalgoritm` инициализировать константу `storage` каким образом здесь необходимо ее инициализировать?
2. как обратится к объекту класса `LRUStorage`, что бы установить у меня capacity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Компилятор говорит, что надо инициализировать поле класса явным образом. Это можно сделать *одним* из способов:

- в конструкторе класса
- добавив простую инициализацию при создании объекта класса

Например:

```
public class LRUAlgoritm<K, V> implements Cache<K, V> {
    private final LRUStorage<K,V> storage = new LRUStorage<>(10); // Явная инициализация с установкой capacity

    // Конструтор
    public LRUAlgoritm(int capacity) {
        this.storage = new LRUStorage<>(capacity);
    }
}
```

Comment: добавил  `public class LRUAlgoritm<K, V> implements Cache<K, V>{
 private final LRUStorage storage = new LRUStorage<>();
  
  public LRUAlgoritm(LRUStorage<K, V> storage) {
         this.storage = storage;
     }`

Comment: @Sergei изменил ответ. Надо выбрать только один способ, оба сразу задействовать не получится. Чтобы задать `capacity` его надо указать при создании объекта `LRUStorage`

Comment: установка capacity  происходит  runner

Comment: Вообще вам явно следует почитать о программировании в Java, в частности что такое класс и как его использовать

Comment: @Sergei еще раз изменил ответ

Comment: @ Yuri Heiko. Сейчас компилятор выбрасывает ошибку The type LRUAlgoritm<K,V>.LRUStorage is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <>. требует удалить <>. но тогда ошибка на константе storage

Comment: Ошибка такая: The final field LRUAlgoritm<K,V>.storage cannot be assigned

Comment: @ Yuri Heiko . посоветуйте неучу, что почитать по этой теме, что бы догнать, Инфы очень много, теряюсь. Хватаю то здесь, то там и ничего путного не получается, не складывается. Если вам не сильно трудно и не обидно отвечать на такой вопрос, пожскажите пожалуста. с уважением. Спасибо.

Comment: @Sergei Ваш код слишком много тем затрагивает, поэтому надо читать последовательно с азов. [Книги по Java и другая литература](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416635/228807)

Comment: @ Yuri Heiko и читаю и курсы смотрю и тесты прохожу пока конечно нечем похвастаться, поэтому и прошу помочь по данному пробелу. а если вы подскажите что можно еще по данной задаче интересное почитать буду очень признателен.

Comment: Из русскоязычных ресурсов мне понравился [этот сайт](http://pr0java.blogspot.com/search/label/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), а вообще продолжайте учить, читать и как можно больше писать код.