# Вопрос новичка по классам

Tags: java

Есть пример:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print("Java easy to learn!");
    }

    public static void print(String s) {
        //напишите тут ваш код
        for(int i = 0;i<4;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

1. Каким образом в метод `print` попал метод `main`, а точнее его содержимое `print("Java easy to learn!");` ?
2. Почему `print("Java easy to learn!");`не конфликтует с `System.out.println(s);` если `print("Java easy to learn!");` это не переменная?
3. `(String[] args)`- что это значит? Я предполагаю что, `String` - это строка, которая содержит массив, а вот `args`, или как во втором методе вообще было написано `(String s)` Что это значит?

Comment: Стоит начать с раздела _начинающим_ : [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416634/186999)

Comment: 1. Метод `print` вызывается из метода `main`. 2. А почему вызов метода `print` должен как-то конфликтовать с содержимым метода `print`? 3. Это значит, что в метод `main` передаётся параметр типа `String[]` с именем `args`.

Comment: `Каким образом в метод print попал метод main` - может быть наоборот?

Comment: Закрытие в стиле «учи матчасть» кажется несколько странным. В любом случае в следующий раз задавайте вопросы по одному.

Comment: @defaultlocale, собственно вопрос и не закрыли

Comment: @Grundy ага, вопрос не закрыт, он (*дьяволический смех*) требует правки :-) На самом деле, я согласен с закрытием, но по-моему логичнее было бы закрыть как слишком общий.

Comment: @defaultlocale, а, это у меня страница не была обновлена и плашка не показывалась. В любом случае: дубликат - это не требует правки :-) это дубликат, хотя в данном случае довольно спорный :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начнем с того, что если у вас возникают такие вопросы, то вам еще рано заниматься классами. Начните с чего-нибудь попроще, например pascal: процедуры, функции, переменные, циклы...

А по существу:

1. В метод `main` попало не содержимое метода `print`. В методе `main` объявлен вызов метода `print`, в котором методу `print` передаются данные, а именно строка *"Java easy to learn!"*
2. `print("Java easy to learn!");` не конфликтует с `System.out.println(s);`, потому что у них разная сигнатура: один называется *"print"*, другой - *"println"*
3. `String[]` - это не строка, которая содержит массив. Это объект, который представляет собой массив строк ([строка_1, строка_2, строка_3, ..., строка_n]). `args` -это имя параметра, который передается методу. В данном случае `main(String[] args)` - означает, что при вызове этого метода ему надо передать в качестве параметра массив строк, а внутри тела метода массивом можно будет пользоваться под именем `args`

Comment: Спасибо, я изучал JS и PHP поверхностно, могу написать небольшие программы, но ООП трудно давалось для восприятия, и я использовал всегда функци. Но здесь Классы, которые возможно дадут толчок для восприятия ООП.

Comment: Возражаю, паскаль не нужен.

Comment: Тогда уж Object pascal получше будет, там и ООП, и процедурки

Comment: Как-то неправильно рекомендовать человеку не учить Java в данном случае. Там нет ничего такого, что при наличии энтузиазма и хорошей литературы не осилит почти любой. Автор просто не с того края подошёл, что обычное дело на старте