# Книги для изучения Java новичку

Tags: java

Добрый день!
Подскажите пожалуйста, реально ли освоить Java как первый язык?
До этого не кодил

Comment: Да, всё реально. Просто надо сесть и начать делать. Из книг советую Head First Java. Там очень простым языком всё написано

Comment: Спасибо))) а практиковаться как?)

Comment: скачать IntelliJ IDEA - среда разработки. там и код писать можно и компилировать

Comment: Ещё почитайте [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-java).

Comment: У некоторых первым языком ассемблер был и ничего, освоили. Java тем более освоите :)

Comment: От души спасибо) книгу качнул)

Comment: Не поленитесь - потратьте всего месяц хотя бы (ну хотя бы пару недель) на ассемблер и си - до джавы. На самые основы.  Поверьте -Вам намного легче будет дальше осваивать и джаву и другие языки. Сам джава программист

Comment: Реально, но будет тяжело. Я сам так изучал. Посмотрите видео Якова Файна, очень доступно объясняет. Практикуйтесь, чем больше тем лучше. Теория без практики очень быстро забывается. Придумайте себе проект и потихоньку его пишите (как пример [http://java-course.ru/student/]). И самое главное английский, минимум intermediate. Без него работу Вы не найдете.

Comment: на торентах нашёл Яков Файн | Программирование на JAVA за 24 часа / Java Programming 24-Hour Trainer (2011) PCRec [H.264]

Answer (score 0):

Все реально :)
Пожалуй, один из [лучших видеокурсов по Java в интернете](https://www.youtube.com/user/KharkovITCourses/playlists), который доступен бесплатно еще и на русском языке

[Сайт](https://javarush.ru/), на котором азы азов бесплатные, дальше за плату

Ну и классика жанра:
Брюс Эккель "Философия Java"

Вот еще [статья](https://dou.ua/lenta/articles/java-beginner-guide-1/), которая подойдет для Вас.

[Задачи](http://codingbat.com/java)

Comment: Спасибо большое, дали надежду

Comment: Слышал JavaRush не очень

Comment: @ЕржанАктанов по какой причине? Теория+практика сразу после теории. Попробуйте- платить сразу же никто не заставляет. У меня брат сейчас по нему учится и нормально

Comment: Я на ДжаваРаше учился в бесплатной версии, отличный ресурс, мощный пинок для старта.

Comment: ааа) понял спасибо

Comment: @ЕржанАктанов только во учат плохому коду и плохому же стилю