# Получение значений в столбце JTable

Tags: java, swing

Существует JTable с 3 столбцами и 100 строками. Нужно по событию на таблице узнать какие данные лежат во втором столбце, т.е. будет коллекция (array) с данными.
Вывести в Sytem.out.println(array);

Answer (score -3):

Дошло!

```
List<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
            array.add((String) table.getValueAt(i, table.getColumnModel().getColumnIndex("Столбец 2")));
        }
        System.out.println(array);
```

Comment: ваш вариант не верен с точки зрения архитектуры. я вам давал верный вариант - надо использовать модель, а не отображение.

Comment: почему же неверно? какие могут быть в данном коде проблемы?

Comment: они у же есть - архитектурные, проблемы с производительностью и потеря типа данных.

Comment: не понимаю что в этом такого, проверял, данные не теряются
тут просто стоит счетчик строк в таблице и занос нужных мне данных

Comment: он решает текущую проблему, но одновременно создаёт несколько багов. Поэтому не смотрят то, что ответ верный для вас он не верный для других, а тот сайт - это коллективная база ответов.

Comment: я вас понял, но на текущем этапе меня устраивает данный код.
Я новичок в java, посоветуйте литературу толковую

Comment: а почему предыдущий вопрос удалили?  Вам надо почитать про MVC и документацию по swing.

Comment: хорошо, а из литературы ? в плане книг

Comment: @user https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-java