# Как написать? Где взять литературу по данному вопросу или где можно изучить материал

Tags: java, сокет

Я хочу написать клиент-серверное приложение на Java - начать с простенького чата. Пока что мне подходит и сервер на компьютере дома. Вопрос первый: как и через что его можно реализовать, может посоветуете фрэймворк или еще что-то?
На сколько я знаю и читал, это можно сделать через сокеты в Java, но у меня и у моего напарника это не выходит:

1. Сначала мы пытались тривиальным, наивным методом реализовать клиент-сервер - не получилось, потому что работала только по локалке, а нам нужно чтобы соединяло разные IP; При чем сколько не читал в инете про это инфы - везде делают клиент-сервер по локальной сети, не по внешнему IP.
2. Мы скачали и использовали туннель ngrok для открытия порта на сервере, чтобы открыто посылать запросы - у нас получилось, но только с одним клиентом. Дальше мы экспериментировали, подключались несколько - но через время или при отправке какого-нибудь смс - все падало - Exception.

Так что у нас не очень то получилось, может посоветуете что-то годное по сокетам?
Я в Java EE вообще не разбираюсь, вот только хочу, но не знаю где взять понятную литературу, чтобы начать, научиться. Может что-то по Java Servlets или JDBC, я просто не шарю что подходит лучше и тд. В идеале хотелось бы передавать не просто сообщения - а уже что-то тяжелее, например картинки.

Comment: Литература здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-java

Comment: @defaultlocale хотелось бы что-то по конкретнее и ближе к моему случаю

Comment: возьмите готовый пример и изучите как он работает

Comment: `а нам нужно чтобы соединяло разные IP; При чем сколько не читал в инете про это инфы - везде делают клиент-сервер по локальной сети, не по внешнему IP.` - советую разобраться как работает сеть(интернет в том числе). Клиент-сервер в локальной сети ничем не отличается от такого же в интернете, единственное ребование - чтобы клиент мог "видеть" сервер, т.е. у сервера должен быть статичный IP адрес, или настроен проброс портов к серверу.

Comment: `мы экспериментировали, подключались несколько - но через время или при отправке какого-нибудь смс - все падало - Exception.` - нужно видеть код чтобы сказать в чем проблема, так сразу невозможно сказать что у вас было не так и какое именно исключение выбрасывалось. https://habrahabr.ru/post/330676/ - вот эта статья, думаю, поможет для начала понять как это должно работать

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-java)

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю поможет или нет. Но если хотите "очень простенько". Можете взять готовый движок Jetty. Почти все сделанно за вас. Использовать WebSocket. Написать простой html, с формой и кнопкой. Скрипт в 10 строчек на js, для соединения к WebSocket. И можно радоваться жизни. В комментариях уже остальное посоветовали.