# Создание объекта в Java. (про тип ссылочной переменной)

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, по поводу создания объекта в Java.

К примеру, имеется такая запись:

```
Computer pc = new Computer();
```

Это значит, что переменной pc типа Computer присваивается ссылка на класс Computer.

Не могу поянть одного: что значит "тип Computer"? Что он хранит? (К примеру есть int, который хранит целочисленные значения, `boolean`, который хранит логчиеские, а что хранят такие типы?)

В чем логика такого ообъявления? Почему не пишется просто `pc = new Comuter;` ? Зачем указывать тип?

Comment: Как раз наоборот, вопрос тебе: почему ты думаешь, что при объявлении int или boolean нужно указать тип, а при указании другого - не нужно? Почему это резко становится не нужным?

Comment: Ну а вообще можно написать `Application app = new Computer();` где `Computer` унаследован от `Application` или  `IApp app = new Computer();` где `IApp` - интерфейс, который компьютерн имплементирует .... и это подведет тебя к теме ООП и полиморфизма в частности))

Comment: Для чего может понадобиться такая запись ? Application app = new Computer();. Зачем ссылаться на дочерний класс?

Comment: А для этого, юный падаван, тебе нужно [почитать книги по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416634/191482)

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв

Answer (score 1):

В переменной `pc` у вас будет ссылка на начало некоторой области памяти в куче. Грубо говоря, чтобы виртуальная машина могла правильно работать с этой ссылкой, ей надо знать какого размера эта область и какие её части к каким полям относятся. Может это ссылка на объект содержащий одно поле типа int, а может объект содержащий 20 полей, часть из которых строки, а часть массивы чисел с плавающей точкой. Вот для этого и указывается тип ссылочной переменной.

Comment: А если взять пример: Computer pc = new Laptop (); (где Laptop - наследник Computer). Т.е. создается переменная pc, которая сслыается на класс Laptop. Данная переменная будет иметь размер класса Computer. Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Повторюсь, я предельно упростил объяснение. Опять же, если очень грубо, при обращении к ссылке типа Computer будет прочитана только часть данных относящихся к этому типу, без части относящейся к Laptop.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо