# "Методы подставки"

Tags: java

На скрине приведен раздел из книги Блинова "Java промышленное программирование".
[image: Скрин]

Не указано в каком отношении находится класс Course с классом CourseHelper. Это ошибка и автор просто забыл добавить, что CourseHelper extends Course или я что-то понимаю не так?

Comment: "методы-подставки" - это шедевр, конечно.  Возьмите [нормальный учебник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Происходит следующее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- `BaseCourse` наследуется от `Course`
- `BaseCourseHelper` наследуется от `CourseHelper`
- `CourseHelper` в методе `getCourse` возвращает экземпляр `Course`
- `BaseCourseHelper` в методе `getCourse` возвращает экземпляр `BaseCourse`

Собственно, автор учебника показывает возможность в дочернем классе (`BaseCourseHelper`) переопределять в методе (`getCourse`) возвращаемый тип (`Course`), но в пределах его дочерних классов (`BaseCourse`).

Comment: не могу не сказать большое спасибо) Очень помогли)

Comment: А зачем все это делается? Если я правильно понимаю, CourseHelper bch = new BaseCourseHelper(); вызовет метод getСourse с BaseCourseHelper, после чего этот вызванный метод вернет объект BaseCourse, который будет присвоен ссылке Course вот здесь course = bch.getCourse, а тут System.out.println(bch.getCourse().id); выводит значение поля id для Course, чтобы он бы и сделал, если бы getCourse() вернул не BaseCourse, а Course.

Comment: Ну это же просто учебный пример, чтобы показать, что такое впринципе скомпилируется. По факту у Course могут быть методы , которые переопределены в BaseCourse. И вызывающая сторона бедет работать с объектом, независимо от того как этот Course был получен.

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего, CourseHelper не связан с Course отношением наследования. Они просто взаимосвязаны, по есть класс написан в "помощь", чтобы с ним обращаться было легче. BaseCourseHelper наследует CourseHelper, это то, что можно вывести из данного кода.

Comment: Тогда я просто не понимаю, что происходит в этом коде)

Comment: Первый абзац говорит о том, что класс Course должен наследоваться от исходного типа (насколько я понимаю, исходным типом будет СourseHelper).

Comment: Ничего подобного, там просто определение функции с возвращаемым значением Course.

Comment: уже понял, спасибо

Answer (score -1):

Course это подкласс класса CourseHelper

Comment: Теперь я немного запутался. А BaseCourse это подкласс Course? Можете, пожалуйста, кратко описать все отношения между классами  BaseCourse, Course, CourseHelper и BaseCourseHelper?

Comment: Наследование является неотъемлемой частью Java. ... Главный наследуемый класс в Java называют суперклассом. Наследующий класс называют подклассом. Получается, что подкласс - это специализированная версия суперкласса, которая наследует все члены суперкласса и добавляет свои собственные уникальные элементы.

Comment: Это я знаю) Я спрашивал о конкретно этом примере. Что от чего наследуется?

Comment: Это не наследование,а инкапсуляция

Comment: Основой инкапсуляции в Java является класс. ... Для этого у методов и переменных внутри класса могут быть модификаторы доступа (public, private). Инкапсуляция означает, что данные объекта недоступны его клиентам непосредственно.

Comment: Вы отвечаете не по теме

Comment: @daniil mankevich, класс который наследуется от другого класса это не подкласс а наследник. подкласс - это класс внутри класса

Comment: Course это не класс,а обьект класса CourseHelper

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Подкласс_(программирование)

Comment: спасибо Flippy,но объснял своим языком

Comment: @daniilmankevich *Course это подкласс класса CourseHelper* или *Course это не класс,а обьект класса CourseHelper* , вы уж определитесь )   (оба  варианта неправильны)

Comment: Тогда что такое Course

Comment: Какой-то класс, определенный выше.