# не понимаю зачем мы возвращаем new объект();

Tags: java

Люди добрый, поясните плиз, зачем или для чего в этом коде мы возвращаем 
`new Pet();`, `new Cat()` и т.д.

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pet pet1 = new Cat();
        Pet cat = pet1.getChild();

        Pet pet2 = new Dog();
        Pet dog = pet2.getChild();
    }

    public static class Pet {
        public Pet getChild() {
            return new Pet();
        }
    }

    public static class Cat extends Pet {
     public Cat getChild(){
         return new Cat();
     }

    }

    public static class Dog extends Pet {
        public Dog getChild(){
            return new Dog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А откуда вы взяли этот фрагмент кода? К нему, вероятно, есть пояснение.

Comment: Рожаем детенышей кошек и собак.

Comment: Но в целом тут показано, что тип возвращаемого методом `getChild()` значения может быть переопределен в дочерних классах.

Comment: Вот такой же по сути вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/722206/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похоже на демонстрацию Полиморфизма.

> Полиморфизм — возможность объектов с одинаковой спецификацией иметь
>   различную реализацию. Язык программирования поддерживает полиморфизм,
>   если классы с одинаковой спецификацией могут иметь различную
>   реализацию — например, реализация класса может быть изменена в
>   процессе наследования. Кратко смысл полиморфизма можно выразить
>   фразой: «Один интерфейс, множество реализаций».
>
> Полиморфизм — один из четырёх важнейших механизмов
>   объектно-ориентированного программирования (наряду с абстракцией,
>   инкапсуляцией и наследованием). Полиморфизм позволяет писать более
>   абстрактные программы и повысить коэффициент повторного использования
>   кода.

Несмотря на то, что у нас имеется один тип Pet с которым мы работаем в коде Main, вызов `getChild()` для каждого из них будет происходить по разному и определен из типа который на самом деле находится в переменной (а не взят из Pet в прямом виде).

Это означает, что если все животные будут иметь детей, то определив для них общее хранилище с типом Pet, мы все равно получим детей нужного класса(котов и собак, а не просто Pet). К примеру воспользовавшись инкубатором для всех. Можно им добавить голос и тогда собаки будут гавкать, а кошки мяукать даже если вызвать их из типа Pet в цикле.

```
class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<Pet>();
        pets.add(new Cat());
        pets.add(new Dog());

        ArrayList<Pet> childs = new Incubator().GetChilds(pets);
    }

    public static class Pet {
        public Pet getChild() {
            System.out.println("Pet");
            return new Pet();
        }
    }

    public static class Cat extends Pet {
     public Cat getChild(){
         System.out.println("Cat");
         return new Cat();
     }

    }

    public static class Dog extends Pet {
        public Dog getChild(){
            System.out.println("Dog");
            return new Dog();
        }
    }

    public static class Incubator
    {
        public ArrayList<Pet> GetChilds(ArrayList<Pet> pets)
        {
            ArrayList<Pet> childs = new ArrayList<Pet>();
            for(Pet pet : pets){
                childs.add(pet.getChild());
            }

            return childs;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное,  надеюсь понял тему.

Answer (score 2):

Вроде так:

1. Есть родительский класс `Pet`, в котором есть конструктор по умолчанию `Pet();`
2. Метод `getChild()` в классе `Pet` возвращает тип `Pet` т.е. рожаем, грубо говоря, какое-то животное.
3. От него наследуются два класса `Cat` и `Dog` и в методах `getChild` этих классов уже рожаем конкретно котика и собачку.

Comment: Т.е. я правильно понимаю, что таким образом создаю новый объект.
Просто как-то странно, я же могу спокойно написать 
Pet dog = new Pet();   (Зачем с этой целью метод городить)

Comment: методы нагорожены, что бы у собаки не родился котенок.
Pet pet1 = new Cat();
Pet cat = pet1.getChild();
вернет нового кота и не нужно делать лишних проверок

Comment: ах. вот где собака зарыта, спасибо.
Точно, если мы не загоним эту часть кода в = new Объект(); в метод
Кто-то своими кривыми руками может написать  = new Непойми_какой_объект();    
Так вот ты какой - полиморфизм

Comment: @DmitriIvanov Нет, он не такой. Пример демонстрирует, что класс-потомок (как `Cat`) может иметь собственную реализацию метода класса-родителя (как `Pet`). При этом важно лишь то, чтобы соблюдалась сигнатура переопределеяемого метода (как `getChild()`) (должны совпадать его имя, аргументы и тип возвращаемого значения), а реализация может быть другой. Здесь мы возвращаем объекты типа `Pet` (куда входят и его потомки), потому что в сигнатуре метода-родителя указано возвращать объекты этого типа. Конкретно в классе `Cat` указано возвращать именно котят, вместо обобщенного домашнего животного.

Comment: @DmitriIvanov Если кто то кривыми руками напишет `= new НепоймиКакойОбъект()`, то это будет не полиморфизм, а отдельный (не переопределенный) метод, возвращающий `НепоймиКакойОбъект`, так как сигнатура метода не будет совпадать с родительской, то есть мы не сможем сделать `Pet cat = new Cat().getChild()` и получить детеныша `НеПоймиКого`, вместо этого мы получим ошибку компиляции.

Answer (score -1):

М.б. на джавараш лучше спросить, что они хотели этим сказать?
А по факту тут объекты типа Пэт, Кэт и Дог умеют рожать детей, а дети это new Cat\Pet\Dog, вот они собственно и возвращаются в методах getChild().