# Как быстро освоить Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, maven, книги

Есть необходимость сделать Web-приложение. Завершить его надо к апрелю. 
У меня есть базовые знания Java. Небольшой опыт создания приложений на C# (WinForm, WPF). Опыта в создании Web-приложений нет.

В начале думал, что смогу на ходу ориентироваться и по примерам писать аналогичный код для себя. Вроде структура кода показалось не такой сложной, но постоянно оказываются какие-то мелочи, которые мешают элементарно самому собрать пустой проект Spring MVC + Maven.

В итоге я нашёл готовый архетип (archetype) для Maven 
GitHub: https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype

И хоть некоторые базовые моменты в сгенерированном проекте оказались интуитивно понятными или легко гуглились, но всё ещё много компонетнов остаются чёрным ящиком для меня. Особенно всякие `config`-и и контексты и прочая настройка.

В связи со всем вышесказанным возник **вопрос**: Есть ли какой-то учебник, который был бы актуален на сегодня (большинство quick-start туториолов в интернете очень старые, а то и вовсе не позволяют создать рабочий проект) и помог бы последовательно освоить написание Web-приложений?

**P.S.** Очень желательно, чтобы литература была на русском языке, но если уж совсем ничего нет, то английский лучше, чем ничего.

Comment: сам понимаешь тут такие вопросы оффтопик, а в [каноничном ответе по Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416634/191482) никто пока ничего о нем не добавил........... могу предложить  http://spring-projects.ru/projects/spring-framework/ и

Comment: @АлексейШиманский тоже расстроился, что в той теме не было книг по Spring.. спасибо за ссылку, буду смотреть.. если смогу собрать по их инструкции хотя бы базовый запускающийся шаблон, то уже можно дальше смотреть =D

Comment: Для тех, **кто собирается ответить на данный вопрос**: тут вопросы о литературе и что почитать являются оффтопиком. Если есть **действительно стоящие** книги к прочтению - заносите в тему  **[Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416634/191482)**

Comment: Самые лучшие и новые туториолы на самом сайте проекта https://spring.io/guides , там используется spring boot и возможность сборки под gradle и maven. При этом можно сразу скачать итоговый результат и разбираться уже в нем, а можно делать по шагам.