# Error:(52, 33) error: incompatible types: ClearDB cannot be converted to Context

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Помогите решить проблему. В классе  ClearDB хочу реализовать разные методы работы с базой (добавить запись, удалить, очистить базу....). Потом использовать их местах где нужно.

```
public class ClearDB  {

    DBHelper dbHelper;
    //private Context context;


    public void Clear () {


        Log.d ("mLog", "Удалены все записи с базы");

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        try {
            dbHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Не возможно инициализировать базу данных");
        }
        try {
            dbHelper.openDataBase();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            throw sqle;
            //Log.d ("mLog", "Ошибка открытия базы данных" + sqle.toString());

        }



        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM logpsw", null);


        final int record = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();// Количество записей в таблице базы
        if (record==0)
        {

            Log.d ("mLog", "Записи в базе отсутствую, добавьте новую запись");
        }

        else {

            try {
                database.delete(DBHelper.TABLE_LOGPWS, null, null);
                Log.d ("mLog", "Удалены все записи с базы");


            } catch (Exception e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("mLog", "Ошибка соединения с базой", e);
               // Toast toastclear1 = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, >"Ошибка соединения с базой  -  " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
               // toastclear1.show();

            }
        }
        dbHelper.close();
        //return true;

    }  

}
```

Вызываю метод:

```
ClearDB clearDB = new ClearDB();
clearDB.Clear();
```

Если вместо `this` использовать `getActivity()` все равно ошибка:

> Error:(52, 33) error: cannot find symbol method getActivity()

Comment: Куда катится эта страна? Иногда просто становится страшно когда видишь такие вопросы - руки опускаются :(

Comment: Я программированием занимаюсь только 1 неделю. Учусь. Потому и задаю такие вопросы. Если не хотите помочь. То подскажите что и где почитать чтобы самому разобраться. Судить легко.

Comment: Почитайте любую книгу [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416635/14141) из раздела Java Core - Начинающим.

Comment: Передайте в метод `Clear()` `context` и используйте его и переименуйте в `clear()` с маленькой буквы и сходите на какие-нибудь курсы, для начала например на онлайн курсы Яндекса

Comment: Немного переделал. Но снова что то не то. 
 Context context;

 try {  
 dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);  
 } catch (Exception e) {  
 e.printStackTrace();  
 Log.d ("mLog", "Ошибка" + e);  
 }  

Ошибка  

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

Вот мое решение, может кому то пригодится.

> public class ClearDB    {
>
> ```
> DBHelper dbHelper;    public Context mContext;
>
> public ClearDB (Context context){
>     mContext = context;
> }
>
> public void mycleardb () {
>
>
>     try {
>         dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>         Log.d ("mLog", "Ошибка" + e);
>     }
>
>     try {
>         dbHelper.createDataBase();
>     } catch (IOException ioe) {
>         throw new Error("Не возможно инициализировать базу данных");
>     }
>     try {
>         dbHelper.openDataBase();
>     } catch (SQLException sqle) {
>         throw sqle;
>
>     }
>
>     SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
>
>     Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM logpsw", null);
>
>
>     final int record = cursor.getCount();
>     cursor.close();// Количество записей в таблице базы
>     if (record==0)
>     {
>        Toast toastclear = Toast.makeText(mContext, "Записи в базе отсутствуют, добавьте новую запись", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
>         toastclear.show();
>         Log.d ("mLog", "Записи в базе отсутствую, добавьте новую запись");
>     }
>
>     else {
>
>         try {
>             database.delete(DBHelper.TABLE_LOGPWS, null, null);
>             Log.d ("mLog", "Удалены все записи с базы");
>             Toast toastclear = Toast.makeText(mContext, "Удалены все записи", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
>             toastclear.show();
>
>         } catch (Exception e) {
>             //e.printStackTrace();
>             Log.d("mLog", "Ошибка соединения с базой", e);
>             Toast toastclear = Toast.makeText(mContext, "Ошибка соединения с базой  -  " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
>             toastclear.show();
>
>         }
>     }
>     dbHelper.close();
>
> } }
> ```