# Практика для начинающего Java программиста

Tags: java

Изучаю Java 8, сейчас читаю Герберт Шилдт Java. Полное руководство. Хорошая книга, все досконально написано но примеры там слишком абстрактные. Думаю есть смысл попробовать писать примитивные gui проложения desktop уровня. Как начать практиковать?

Comment: Вам наверное сюда [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-java).

Comment: О, книги это хорошо) осталось только зуд в руках унять)

Comment: 1) Воспользуйтесь поиском, здесь много практических примеров, которые полностью воиспроизводимые, т.е. копи+паста и можете руки больше не чесать. 2) Ознакомтесь со [справкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), задавать два вопроса в одном не желательно.

Comment: Для практики. Посмотрите тут https://tproger.ru/digest/competitive-programming-practice/
И тут https://proglib.io/p/project-list/

Answer (score 1):

1. Я практиковал **Java** так. Писал игры и программы с видео, *списывал*. Затем построчно гуглил. А с опытом ко мне пришло понимание как это работает.Метод неплохой, мне он как раз подходит для практики и изучения одновременно. Единственный возможный минус - некоторые вещи можно узнавать **только** читая специальные книги или слушая специальные лекции. Но думаю это не проблема.
2. Олимпиадные задания по программированию. У тебя есть чёткая **цель** и ты её должен выполнить с минимальными расходами. Да, и тут в основном не программирование, а алгоритмы, тоже неплохо.

Надеюсь мой ответ поможет тебе в изучении языка, удачи!