# Конец кода, но не конец консоли

Tags: java

Как сделать так, чтобы при запуске консоль не останавливалась после выполнения кода, а продолжала работать. И пользователь мог вводить в нее данные.

Comment: Сделать цикл `do..while`, который будет выполняться до тех пор, пока пользователь не введет, например, `exit`, не подходит?

Comment: Я слишком глуп чтоб сделать цикл.Можно готовый код?

Comment: [Тут](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java/Операторы_цикла_for,_while,_do_..._while) и [тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/do-while.php) можно почитать о циклах. Вообще, было бы неплохо почитать книги по Java. [В этой статье](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/Книги-и-учебные-ресурсы-по-java) есть достаточно примеров книг для программистов разного уровня.