# Перевод часов в секунды

Tags: java

Здравствуйте.
 Простая задача не проходит валидацию.

```
public class mySeconds{
public static getMySeconds(int i){
 return i*60*60;
 }
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println(getMySeconds(5));
System.out.println(getMySeconds(3)); 
 }
}
```

Не прошу делать за меня, подскажите где искать, что почитать?

Comment: `public static int getMySeconds(int i){` ?

Comment: Если возникает ошибка, то нужно указать текст сообщения об ошибке и строку, на которой она возникает. В идеале предварительно нужно самому поискать информацию по этой ошибке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в объявлении метода.

```
public static getMySeconds(int i)
```

У любого метода должен быть объявлен возвращаемый тип (в вашем случае int). У вас он не указан.

```
public static int getMySeconds(int i)
```

Вот так должно выгладеть объявление метода.

Почитать советую любую книгу по Java для начинающих. Благо, подборок в интернете достаточно.

Успехов!

Comment: *Благо, подборок в интернете достаточно*. Например у нас 
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634