# Вызов метода toString() в Java

Tags: java, методы

Чем обусловлен безусловный вызов метода toString() в данном случае? И почему не происходит безусловного вызова второго метода?

```
class AnyClass{

    private Object obj;

public AnyClass(Object cif){
    obj = cif;
}

public String toString(){
    return obj.toString();
}

public String str(){
    return obj.toString();
}
}

  class AnonymClasses {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      AnyClass ac = new AnyClass(new Integer(10));
      System.out.println(ac);
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Системный метод `println()` (вывести в поток вывода, обычно на экран) вызывает метод `toString()`всякий раз, когда  в качестве аргумента получает какой-либо объект, так заложено в его коде.

Так как объект может иметь самую разную реализацию, то для того, чтобы его гарантировано можно было "напечатать" в классе `Object` определен метод `toString()`, который по умолчанию выводит имя объекта и еще сопутствующую информацию.

Метод `println()` не может знать "вид" произвольного объекта и чтобы отобразить его, обращается к методу `toString()`, который обязательно присутствует в любом объекте и возвращает строку, которую можно напечатать.

Даже если вы не переопределите в своем классе метод `toString()` будет использован метод класса `Object`

Вам самому не нужно вызывать этот метод, это делает системный метод печати, чтобы гарантировано получить ожидаемый результат.

Ваши собственные методы не будут вызываться системными методами, потому что они о них ничего не знают, что бы вы там не написали.

Comment: Большое спасибо за четкий и развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 11):

Просто смотрим реализации

```
public void print(Object obj) {
    write(String.valueOf(obj));
}
```

Спускаемся ниже

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

Ну как бы всё.

`toString()` -  стандартный метод в классе `Object`, `str` - нет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. То есть если в классе используются объекты разных типов и в этом же классе описаны стандартные методы для этих типов то эти методы будут безусловно применены к объектам? Если да, то для чего это нужно?

Comment: @АлександрКочуров думаю вам стоит прочитать о стандартных методах класса `Object` и о наследовании/полифморфизме в `Java`. Возможно что-то отсюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-java вам поможет.

Comment: Я знаю что все классы наследуются от Object и наследуют его методы и что в этом случае я переопределяю этот метод, но почему он вызывается тогда когда я его не вызывал мне не понятно. Если я создам свой класс, расширю им AnyClass и  переопределю его метод, то он не будет безусловно вызван как в случае с наследованием от Object. И если бы я хотел прочитать целую книгу чтобы найти ответ, я бы так и сделал.

Comment: @АлександрКочуров Вы можете вообще убрать из своего класса метод  `toString()`, он всё равно будет работать потому что, есть в родительском классе Object.

Comment: Я это понимаю. Но почему переопределенный метод вызывается сам по себе?

Comment: @АлександрКочуров читайте первые строки ответа... что значит сам по себе? Вы его вызываете просто не напрямую.

Comment: Вот я и спросил почему происходит этот "не прямой" вызов. Ответ уже получил. Спасибо за участие.

Comment: программисту понятно, что написано в вашем ответе и как это решает проблему в вопросе, но новичку иногда трудно понять такое очевидное для программиста объяснение.

Comment: Ну, как сказать, я спросил "Почему?" мне ответили на "Как?". Из реализации этого метода не следует что он должен быть безусловно вызван.

Comment: @АлександрКочуров следует) для вас это может _пока_ не очевидно, но немного изучив java оно действительно следует и очевидным образом. И да, изучите как в java работает полиморфизм - существенно упростит дальнейшее обучение.