# Уроки по Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Посоветуйте хорошую литературу или видеоуроки по Spring Boot для расширенного изучения на русском языке. Подробно объясняющую книгу.

Comment: Английский вообще не вариант? P. S. Я так понимаю, что официальная документация отпадает?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-java)

Answer (score 1):

**Видеоуроки:**

- [Spring Boot](https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwwk4BHih4fho6gmaAwdHYZ6QQq0aE7Zi)
- [Spring Web Flow](https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwwk4BHih4fjkwOmdl_slp_m1IdM5UYF4)
- [Spring Security](https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwwk4BHih4fg5rAA-AEdp0PiahqFaybbv)

В идеале, параллельно с просмотром видеоуроков читать официальную документацию или найти хорошую книгу на русском (если с английским совсем плохо), так как там материал более систематизирован.

Уроки в интернете лучше пока не читать. Толку от них (для новичка) мало: будете уметь делать конкретные вещи, но понимание самого фреймворка будет отсутствовать. В итоге, ошибка и Вы будете тратить уйму времени на ее решение.

Это мое мнение, Вам решать ;)

Answer (score 1):

Вот нашел ресурс по [Spring Boot на русском](http://spring-projects.ru/projects/spring-boot/):

> Сайт посвящен java-фреймворку Spring, а также другим библиотекам и инструментам, которые основаны на нем или непосредственно используют его. Сайт является неофициальным русскоязычным зеркалом, в котором я буду размещать свои переводы оригинальных материалов, документаций и новостей. Также, будут опубликованы собственные материалы, проекты и переводы из других источников. Переводы документаций будут осуществляться для каждой версии(GA), за исключением snapshot'ов.

[Spring Boot: от начала до продакшена](https://habr.com/post/257223/).

[Вебинар «Spring Boot 2. Весенний подарок разработчикам»](https://dou.ua/calendar/20161/).