# Интерфейс Intelj Idea ultimate, нет кнопки для создания Spring приложений

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

Всем Привет, смотрю видео курс по Spring на ютубе и там при создании нового проекта кнопка для создания проекта есть кнопка "Spring", a у меня только кнопка

[image: Srping initializr]

и не могу понять как создавать проект, может кто-нибудь помочь просто добавить кнопку 'Spring'

[image: вот так].

Comment: Возможно урок устарел или IDE обновилась с момента урока. Возможно, вам стоит создать просто gradle/maven проект и в него спринг в качестве зависимостей просто добавить.

Comment: Какая версия intellij idea? Help -> About

Comment: Вот ещё один ресурс [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/820340/204920).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте тыкнуть правой кнопкой мыши на модуль вашего проекта -> Add framework support.. И там должен быть спринг, веб, hibernate и тп