# Мануал JAVA на русском

Tags: java

Ребята нужна не книга а мануал по Java.
Что то вроде php.net для PHP

То есть необходим справочник с функциями а не учебник

Comment: а ссылки можно??

Comment: Если совсем плохо с английским, пользуйтесь Google Translate

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-java)

Answer (score 4):

Документации по Java API на русском языке не существует. По крайней мере актуальной.