# Проблемы с созданием апплета на java

Tags: java

пытаюсь учить java, и в освоении апплетов я зашёл в тупик. Учу по книге и там в примере даётся такой код, но меня смущает HTML код(Т.е он просто вставляется в блок многострочного комментария после импортов) прямо в Java коде(Именно так показывается в книге)

```
import java.awt.*;

import java.applet.*; 

`/* <applet code = "main" width = 100 height=100></applet> */`

class Main extends Applet{

    public void init(){

    }
    public void start(){

    }
    public void stop(){

    }
    public void destroy(){

    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawString("Hello World", 10,10);
    }
}
```

Но он не работает. Выводится ошибка:

> Error: Main method not found in class MyPackage.Main, please define the main method as:
>     public static void main(String[] args) or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Comment: в чем код пишете? В eclipse есть специальная конфигурация для запуска апплетов, в других ide должны быть аналоги. Вообще апплеты устарели, можно раздел в книге пролистать (или взять книгу [поновее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416635/190934))

Comment: Пользуюсь я IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition. Пытался найти, но не нашёл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Комментарий содержащий html-код нужен для того, чтобы апплет можно было запустить утилитой [appletviewer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/appletviewer.html), входящей в состав JDK и предназначенной для облегчения тестирования апплетов. Но, во-первых, класс должен быть публичным, иначе загрузить его не получится. Во-вторых, регистр букв в названии класса имеет значение.

```
import java.awt.*;

import java.applet.*; 

/* <applet code = "Main" width=100 height=100></applet> */

public class Main extends Applet {
    public void init() {}
    public void start() {}
    public void stop() {}
    public void destroy() {}

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Hello World", 10, 10);
    }
}
```

Компилируем апплет

```
$ javac Main.java
```

И запускаем

```
$ appletviewer Main.java
```

Только имейте ввиду, что с 2015-го года многие браузеры перестали их поддерживать. С сентября 2017 Oracle объявили технологию устаревшей. Скорее всего, до конца года или в следующем её окончательно уберут из Java.

Comment: Технология объявлена depricated начиная с Java 9. [JEP 289: Deprecate the Applet API](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/289) и  [Class Applet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html)

Answer (score 0):

Апплет нужно запускать по-другому, не как консольную программу. Не нажимать кнопку "Выполнить", а в НетБинс, например, нажать на значок апплета слева правой кнопкой мыши и выбрать "Выполнить файл" и всё получится.