# Проблемы в понимании работы Spring'a

Tags: java, spring-mvc, freemarker, spring-jdbc

недавно смотрел видео по созданию веб-приложения с помощью Spring MVC и Freemarker и пытался понять что и к чему. На 1:20:00  https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=4864&v=DclLJt8zDWk он создаёт такой сервлет

```
@PostMapping("/addUser")
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user,Model model){
    userService.save(user);
    return "redirect:/users";
}
```

Далее он создаёт файл-страничку с формой для добавления нового пользователя:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create User page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="user"  action="/addUser" method="post">
    <p>Name</p>
    <input title="Name" type="text" name="name">
    <p>Email</p>
    <input title="Email" type="text" name="email">
    <p>Age</p>
    <input title="Age" type="text" name="age">        
    <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Мне не совсем понятно, откуда в методе addUser, после отправки данных с браузера на сервер, в объекте model появляется новый атрибут "user", где мы задали его имя и как он смог собрать объект User, а не отдельные значения имени, возраста и почты?

Comment: Это потому, что надо не видео смотреть, а учебник прочитать.

Comment: Хорошо, какой учебник, дайте ссылку/название

Comment: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416634/204271), раздел Spring.