# javax.swing не выводится окно

Tags: java, swing

Написал следующий код на java. Программа завершается корректно, но при запуске окно не выводится на экран. Среда разработки IntelIJ. В чем проблема? Спасибо.

```
package com.calculator.main;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Start {

    private JFrame main_window;

    public Start(){

        // Связываем новое окно с полем main_window Задаём заголовок окна
        main_window = new JFrame("Calculator v1");

        // Задаём высоту и ширину главного окна калькулятора в пикселях
        main_window.setSize(250, 350);

        // Помещаем окно в центре монитора
        main_window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // Устанавливаем запрет на масштабирование окна
        main_window.setResizable(false);

        /* Задаем поведение главного окна при нажатии на кнопку "крестик".
        Параметр EXIT_ON_CLOSE закрывает окно и останавливает процесс выполнения программы*/
        main_window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Делаем окно видимым
        main_window.setVisible(true);

        main_window.add(new Panel());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы в методе `main` (а именно с него начинается выполнение программы) не делаете ничего... Добавьте в него `new Start();`

Comment: Рекомендую почитать [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416634/204271) и [это](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Работа программы начинается с метода `main`. В вашем случаи он пуст, и программа думает, что ничего делать не надо. Поскольку у вас есть конструктор класса Start. то в теле `main` вставьте ранее подсказанную строку:
`new Strat();`

Answer (score 0):

Главный метод должен выглядеть так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Start();
    }
```

Хочу добавить, то, что метод `setVisible(true);` должен всегда стоять последним, он позволяет отображать информацию, если после него что-то добавлять, это не отобразится