# Непонятная конструкция в объектах

Tags: java

Начал не так давно изучать язык JAVA. Просматривая разные туториалы и примеры программ, неоднократно сталкиваюсь с непонятными для меня конструкциями. Нигде не могу найти объяснение такого кода.

Подскажите в какую сторону копать или хотя-бы как это называется? В настоящее время я вижу это, как мы создаем объект и передаем в его конструктор другой объект, в котором мы вызываем метод.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
```

Comment: "Подскажите в какую сторону копать" -  а какие книги по Java вы уже прочитали?  Про потоки (в смысле стримы, а не треды) рассказывается в каждой книге по базам языка и поясняется почему так

Comment: Да, все именно так, как вы понимаете. В конструкторы можно передавать объекты, а возвращаемый тип метода совпадает с тем, который принимает на входе конструктор.

Comment: В целом вот список книг https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-java

Comment: @Сергей Мишин, думаю лучше человеку сначала разобраться с конструкторами и вообще базовыми вещами, иначе начав с потоков или еще чего более сложного, можно вообще ничего не понять

Comment: "создаем объект и передаем в его конструктор другой объект, в котором мы вызываем метод." -- нет, это неверное понимание. В конструктор мы передаем не объект, в котором вызываем метод, а результат, возвращаемый методом объекта (в вашем случае методом `getInputStream()` объекта `socket`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так и есть, при создании объекта в конструктор могут передаваться другие объекты, в Java это обычное дело. В данном случае происходит следующее:

1. У класса Socket есть метод getInputStream(), который возвращает объект типа InputStream.
2. У класса InputSteamReader есть конструктор, который принимает в качестве параметра объект типа InputStream, а мы его уже создали в п.1 и передаём туда.
3. У класса BufferedReader есть конструктор, который также принимает в качестве параметра объект типа Reader, а у нас уже в п.2 создан его потомок - InputSteamReader. 
   В общем получается как бы "матрешка", где создание объекта происходит непосредственно в самом конструкторе другого объекта. Можно, конечно, создавать объекты отдельно, присваивая их ссылочным переменным соответствующего типа, но так получается больше кода.

Answer (score 2):

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

можно написать

```
Stream stream = socket.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
```

Тогда Вы увидите, что утверждение

> передаем в его конструктор другой объект, в котором мы вызываем метод

неверно.