# Наследование и конструкторы

Tags: java

Прочитал в общих сведениях о конструкторах что, Конструкторы не наследуются, источник: [Клик](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1391-konstruktorih-klassov-java-jdk-15)

Сделал такой пример и получилось, что конструкторы наследуются:

```
public class Car {

    public Car() {
        System.out.println("Машина");
    }
}

public class Bmw extends Car {

}


public class Qwerty {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car car = new Car();
        Bmw bmw = new Bmw();
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоли:

Машина
Машина

Comment: За Вас поработал компилятор.

Comment: @Igor а как научиться понимать вот такие вещи? То есть прочитал что наследование конструкторов не работает, а по факту работает на практике, тогда что говорить на собеседовании чтобы сказать правильно?

Comment: @MikeMclaren для понимания таких вещей надо внимательно прочитать учебник, только и всего.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev с английским проблема, я учу каждый день. А книжки и статьи читаю по максимому

Comment: @MikeMclaren есть множество прекрасных учебников на русском.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev подскажите пожалуйста, я читаю "Изучаем Java" Кети Сиерра, какие еще есть? Я всё прочту!

Comment: @MikeMclaren хороший выбор для старта. После неё можно начать читать один учебник за другим из раздела "Средний уровень" [этого списка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416634/204271).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Так вы же сами говорили на русском кроме Сиерры, в остальных книгах перевод не очень?)

Comment: @MikeMclaren не очень перевод у Шилдта, про остальные я этого не говорил. Впрочем, огрехи могут встречаться и в других учебниках, но с ростом объёма знаний они будут меньше мешать.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev спасибо большое!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Конструкторы не наследуются. В этом легко убедиться, немного исправив ваши классы

```
class Car {
    public Car(int speed) {
        System.out.println("Машина");
    }
}

class Bmw extends Car { }

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bmw bmw = new Bmw(200);
    }
}
```

При компиляции получите ошибку

```
Example.java:7: error: constructor Car in class Car cannot be applied to given types;
class Bmw extends Car { }
^
  required: int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
App.java:13: error: constructor Bmw in class Bmw cannot be applied to given types;
        Bmw bmw = new Bmw(200);
                  ^
  required: no arguments
  found: int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
2 errors
```

Из ошибки понятно, что в `Bmw` нет конструктора принимающего целочисленный аргумент, а значит он не унаследовался от `Car`.

Когда вы явно не объявляете конструктор, компилятор создаёт конструктор без аргументов, содержащий ровно одну строку кода - вызов конструктора без аргументов родительского класса:

```
class Bmw extends Car {                                               
  Bmw();                                                              
    Code:                                                             
       0: aload_0                                                     
       1: invokespecial #1    // Method Car."<init>":()V
       4: return                                                      
}
```

Чтобы создать объект, виртуальная машина должна вызвать конструктор его класса и всех родительских, вплоть до `Object`. Поэтому вы видите вывод строки "Машина".

Comment: Какой раз поражаюсь вашими очень расширенными ответами, огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Если класс не содержит явного конструктора, то определяется конструктор по умолчанию. Если класс не наследуется от другого класса, то конструктор по умолчанию умеет пустое тело. Иначе в нём вызывается конструктор родительского класса без аргументов.

Получается, что в классе Bmw неявно определён такой конструктор:

```
public Bmw() {
    super();
}
```

[Спецификация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9).

Этот случай не является наследованием конструкторов, потому что вы в любом случае создаёте объект Bmw с помощью конструктора класса Bmw, пусть и объявленного неявно. Если вы добавите в класс Bmw любой конструктор явно, то конструктор по умолчанию создаваться уже не будет.

Comment: а как научиться понимать вот такие вещи? То есть прочитал что наследование конструкторов не работает, а по факту работает на практике, тогда что говорить на собеседовании чтобы сказать правильно?

Comment: @MikeMclaren, при чём здесь наследование конструкторов? При создании объекта Bmw вызывается именно конструктор класса Bmw. Так получилось, что он дефолтный, поэтому работает так же, как  и конструктор класса Car. Вам ничего не мешает явно написать конструктор из моего ответа. От этого механизм создания объектов не поменяется.

Comment: @MikeMclaren, если вы добавите в класс Bmw ещё один  любой конструктор, то конструктор по умолчанию создаваться уже не будет и вам придётся описывать явно конструктор без аргументов.

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!