# Junior Java разработчик

Tags: java

**Подскажите пожалуйста последовательность изучения  JAVA  что-бы стать Junior разработчиком**

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-java)

Comment: подумай сначала, надо ли тебе [это](https://ebanoe.it/)

Answer (score 1):

```
1.Найди наставника
2.Найди наставника
3.Найди наставника
...
```

Конечно можно нарекомендовать много книг, официальную документацию в конце-концов. Но только человек, который уже в теме способен быстро и что называется "на пальцах" объяснить, как это работает.

И далеко не все курсы могут быть полезны, кстати (могут просто по верхушкам тем пробежаться). И технологии развиваются семимильными шагами и на одну и ту же вещь могут быть противоположные взгляды. А наставник возьмет и проведет тебя через все эти терни и даст свою оценку и расскажет, как оно все на практике.

Из личного опыта... полтора, даже два года самостоятельно учился, разбирался... а потом с удивлением наблюдал картину, как моего же уровня человек спокойно достигнул с наставником за пол года.

Answer (score 1):

Изучаем Java SE на уровне JDK 1.8, потом идём на сайты с вакансиями и смотрим, какие технологии требуются от специалистов уровня junior. Часто это Git, Spring, Hibernate, SQL, Maven/Gradle, но могут быть вариации. Выбираем те, которые встречаются чаще всего, однако, в большинстве случаев и вышеперечисленного должно хватить. Разбираемся по-минимуму, пишем своё небольшое web-приложение, а лучше несколько, и можно идти пытаться штурмовать собеседования.

На деле же, разобраться в этом всём с нуля и в одиночку очень сложно и долго, поэтому, как вариант, посмотреть на всякие онлайн курсы. Для больших городов ещё можно попытаться попасть в центр подготовки джунов одной из крупных IT-компаний (EPAM, SoftServe и прочие). Обучение там бесплатно и лучшие выпускники сразу переходят в штат, однако и конкуренция там очень высока.