# Java и web-приложение

Tags: java, веб-программирование

Около полугода учу java, на данный момент довольно неплохо знаю core, перерешал кучу задач и написал одного вк бота. И сейчас загорелся идеей сделать свое web-приложение (сайт с редактированием картинок). Так вот хотелось бы узнать, с помощью каких технологии сейчас реализуют web-проекты? Что мне нужно изучать, чтобы создать свое web-приложение? Как мне научиться правильно планировать структуру своего проекта? Свободного времени у меня много и я хочу полностью посвятить себя java.

Comment: Java EE и Spring.

Comment: Walls C. - Spring in Action - 2019

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-java)

Answer (score 1):

Конечно Java EE и Spring это круто, но сейчас пошла такая тенденция, использования фреймворков в слепую. Рынок набит джунами которые размахивают своим спрингом, как работает **cors** или или **http** толком ответить не могут.

В качестве учебных целей полезно написать свое первое веб приложение на core java, я не говорю что нужно пытаться учесть все особенности типа аутентификации или сессий, хотя и это посильная задача.

После этого, вооружившись спрингом или JavaEE вы уже будете понимать что Вам нужно сделать на более глубоком уровне, вы будете понимать что делает фреймворк, а не просто в слепую набивать код кусками найденными в интернете, и тем более будет мотивация использовать фреймворк, а главное, я надеюсь, будет понимание, когда его можно вовсе не использовать :)

В общем случае полезно знать веб технологии, в которых достаточно много тонкостей, не имеющих отношения к языку программирования, на котором реализуется веб приложение.

Крайне полезно понимать что ждет от сервера фронтенд, по этому в этот лес тоже стоит заглянуть и отныне html js и css (как минимум) - Ваши заклятые друзья.

---

Вот простенький пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Kali fractal</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas></canvas>

    <script type='glsl/vertex'>
      attribute vec2 coords;
      void main(void) {
        gl_Position = vec4(coords.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
      }
    </script>

    <script type='glsl/fragment'>precision highp float;
       uniform vec4 mr; // (m)ouse position and screen (r)esolution
       void main(void) {
         vec2 p = gl_FragCoord.xy;
         vec2 q = (p + p - mr.ba) / mr.b;
         for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
              q = abs(q)/dot(q,q) -  mr.xy/mr.zw;
         gl_FragColor = vec4(q, q.x/q.y, 1.0);
       }
    </script>

    <script>
      let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
      canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
      canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
      let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl') || canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
      var h = gl.drawingBufferHeight;
      var w = gl.drawingBufferWidth;

      let pid = gl.createProgram();
      shader('glsl/vertex', gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
      shader('glsl/fragment', gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
      gl.linkProgram(pid);
      gl.useProgram(pid);

      let array = new Float32Array([-1,  3, -1, -1, 3, -1]);
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
      gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, array, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

      let al = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "coords");
      gl.vertexAttribPointer(al, 2 /*components per vertex */, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
      gl.enableVertexAttribArray(al);

      let mr = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'mr');  // (m)ouse position and screen (r)esolution

      window.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
      window.addEventListener('touchmove', draw);

      draw();

      function draw(e) {
        let ev = e && e.touches ? e.touches[0] : e;
        let x = ev ? ev.clientX : 250;
        let y = ev ? h - ev.clientY: 111;
        gl.uniform4f(mr, x, y, w, h);
        gl.viewport(0, 0, w, h);
        gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3 /* 3 vertices */);
      }

      function shader(name, type) {
        let src = [...document.scripts].find(s => s.type === name).innerText;
        let sid = gl.createShader(type);
        gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
        gl.compileShader(sid);
        gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
      }
    </script>

    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

`SimpleWebServer.java`

```html
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SimpleWebServer implements HttpHandler {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 0);
        server.createContext("/", new SimpleWebServer("/", "./static/"));
        server.start();
        System.out.println("server started, please visit http://localhost:8080/index.html");
    }

    private String routePath;
    private String fsPath;

    private Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>(){{
        put("html", "text/html");
    }};

    public SimpleWebServer(String path, String filesystemPath) {
        routePath = path;
        fsPath = filesystemPath;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange http) throws IOException {
        OutputStream outputStream = http.getResponseBody();
        http.getRequestBody();
        String request = http.getRequestURI().getRawPath();
        byte[] result;
        int code;
        try {
            try {
                String path = fsPath + request.substring(routePath.length());
                System.out.println("requested: " + path);
                result = read(new FileInputStream(path)).toByteArray();
                String ext = request.substring(request.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                if (headers.containsKey(ext))
                    http.getResponseHeaders().add("Content-Type", headers.get(ext));
                code = 200;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                result = (404 + " " + request).getBytes();
                code = 404;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            result = sw.getBuffer().toString().getBytes();
            code = 500;
        }
        http.sendResponseHeaders(code, result.length);
        outputStream.write(result);
        outputStream.close();
    }

    static ByteArrayOutputStream read(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int nRead;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
            buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
        }
        buffer.flush();
        is.close();
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

более/менее универсальный (и несложный) ответ/совет:

Сборщик/менеджер зависимостей (Maven или Gradle), Фреймворк (SpringBoot), БД (PostgreSQL или MySQL) + SpringData и Hibernate, контейнер для выполнения java кода (Tomcat), Logger (Log4j), Тестирование (JUnit + Mockito)

кроме этого (позже) пригодится nginx и Linux Server (например Debian) - это чтобы уже написанное приложение в интернете крутилось

P.S.
Могут быть вариации