# Возможно ли web приложение на java работающее локально?

Tags: java

Только начинаю изучать Java и возник вопрос. Можно ли написать приложение (к примеру органайзер), который будет работать в браузере, но для которого не нужно создавать web сервер, просто как то запускать в браузере на ПК под Windows? Или для таково варианта только десктоп приложение? Если возможно, что необходимо будет изучить кроме Java Core?

Это часть идеи, общая - написать органайзер(просто для себя для обучения), который бы работал на Android как приложение и его веб версия, с синхронизацией базы через облако типа яндекс/гугл диска.

Comment: В Java есть простенький веб сервер https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/981555/188366

Comment: "В Java есть простенький веб сервер" - запускать его получиться только через IDE (в Идее запустил, спасибо) или возможно скомпоновать как то в файл для более простого запуска?

Comment: Вам ничего не мешает поставить локальный сервер и пускай он крутится с вашим приложением.

Comment: @fantomrik можно конечно

Comment: "Вам ничего не мешает поставить локальный сервер и пускай он крутится с вашим приложением" - ну мало ли захочется поделится данным приложением с кем то, кто далек от программирования.

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, спасибо! Буду изучать!

Comment: Ну всегда можно передать тот же запакованный tomcat, цена вопроса 11Мб. Зато взамен получить готовую структуру, которую в противном случае придется писать самому. С другой стороны самому тоже может быть полезно пописать)

Comment: @Alex Krass а если это несколько пользователей и им захочется просто использовать программу без доп телодвижений? Или запакованный tomcat элементарно распаковывается и запускается? Просто хотелось бы, что бы просто программа просто запускалась двойным щелчком мышки или подобным способом. Но как выше ответил **Stranger in the Q**, видимо можно так сделать средствами самой Java

Comment: По идее его можно распространять просто запихав в zip и потом обратно распаковав ну нужном компьютере. Дальше просто запустить .bat через ссылку и готово. Или можно даже сделать launcer на декстопе, чтобы он был красивее. Можно сделать и на Java Core, тут только вопрос, будет ли это быстрее, удобнее и не придется ли писать кучу лишнего - это наверное можно тоже уточнить у @StrangerintheQ.