# Про return более подробно?

Tags: java

Начал изучать программирование и начал с языка Java и столкнулся с трудностью, поэтому прошу помощи.

Объясните пожалуйста про `return` более подробно. Почему в примере кода `return` используется только в случае с `amountToWithdraw`, и почему его не используют также в случае с `amountToDeposit?`

Пример кода:

```java
public class SavingsAccount {

  int balance;

  public SavingsAccount(int initialBalance){
    balance = initialBalance;
  }
  public void checkBalance(){
    System.out.println("Hello!");
    System.out.println("Your balance is "+balance);
  }
  public void deposit(int amountToDeposit){
    balance = balance + amountToDeposit;
    System.out.println("You just deposited "+amountToDeposit);
  }
  public int withdraw(int amountToWithdraw){
    balance = balance - amountToWithdraw;
    System.out.println("You just withdrew "+amountToWithdraw);
    return amountToWithdraw;
  }
  public String toString(){
    return "This is a savings account with " + balance + " saved.";
   }  
  public static void main(String[] args){
    SavingsAccount savings = new SavingsAccount(2000);    

    savings.checkBalance();    

    savings.withdraw(300);    

    savings.checkBalance();    

    savings.deposit(600);    

    savings.checkBalance();

    savings.deposit(600);

    savings.checkBalance();

    System.out.println(savings);
  }       
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Методы, в зависимости от того, что нужно автору программы, могут возвращать значение того или иного типа, а могут не возвращать никакого значения. Те, которые вычисляют и возвращают какое-то значение, по смыслу соответствуют математическому понятию функции (типа `у = sin(x)`), и в некоторых языках так и называются -- `функции`. Те, которые просто совершают какие-то действия, но не возвращают никакого значения, по смыслу соответствуют тому, что в других языках называется `процедуры`.  Методы первого типа в `Java` описываются с указанием типа результата и **обязаны** явно использовать как минимум один оператор `return` с указанием возвращаемого значения, причем компилятор проверяет, что тот или иной из этих операторов выполнится неизбежно, при любых обстоятельствах (кроме случаев возникновения исключений). Ведь внутри тела метода могут вычисляться несколько разных значений, а компилятор должен знать, какое именно из них должно являться результатом вычисления функции. Например:

```
public double sqrtOfSinMultByCos(double a, double b) {
  double sin = Math.sin(a);
  double cos = Math.cos(b);
  return Math.sqrt(sin * cos);
}

public int badMethod(int a) { // Не откомпилируется,
  // сругается "This method must return a result of type int" 
  if (a >= 10) {
    return a / 10;   // оператор return есть, 
                     // но его выполнение не гарантировано:  
  } else {           // В этом случае return не выполнился бы 
    System.out.println("a меньше 10"); 
  }
}
```

Методы второго типа, которые просто выполняют какие-то действия и не возвращают никакого значения, описываются с ключевым словом `void`, которое используется вместо указания типа результата, и **не обязаны**, но могут иметь явный оператор `return`. Например:

```
public void printSqrtOfSinMultByCos(double a, double b) {
  double sin = Math.sin(a);
  double cos = Math.cos(b);
  System.out.println(Math.sqrt(sin * cos));
}
```

В норме код такого метода выполняется до конца, затем происходит возврат к выполнению того участка кода, который следует за вызовом метода. Если по логике метода код метода не обязан выполняться весь, то можно использовать оператор `return` в нескольких местах кода, не обязательно в конце. Это может упростить структуру кода и улучшить его читаемость:

```
// Найти макс. x, x <= 10, на которое делится n
publiс void reportDivisibility(int n) {
  if (n % 10 == 0) {
    System.out.println("n делится на 10"); return; 
  }
  // Если n делится на 10, другие условия не проверяются
  // TODO Добавить проверку других признаков делимости 
  if (n % 3 == 0) {
    System.out.println("n делится на 3"); return; 
  }
  if (n % 2 == 0) {
    System.out.println("n -- четное"); return; 
  }
  System.out.println("n не делится на числа 2..10";      
}
```

Этот же прием можно использовать и в методах, возвращающих результат:

```
public BigDecimal max(BigDecimal a, BigDecimal b) {
  if (a.compareTo(b) > 0) 
    return a;
  return b;
}
```

Здесь `return b` выполняется только в том случае, если не выполнилось условие оператора `if` и соответственно не выполнилось `return a;`.

Comment: спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ с примерами. По `return` все стало понятным.

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от возвращаемого типа метода к которому вы обращаетесь. В вашем случае возвращаемым типом метода `public int withdraw(int amountToWithdraw)` является тип `int`, соответственно метод должен иметь точку выхода со значением типа `int`. Для метода `public String toString()` это `return "This is a savings account with " + balance + " saved.";` у которого тип `String` и.т.д.

А метод `public void checkBalance()` помечен как `void` и не возвращает ничего. Можно преждевременно прекратить выполнение вызвав пустой `return;`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Comment: @Daryn Serikbayev
Почему по аналогии с `public int withdraw(int amountToWithdraw)`  не написать 
`public int deposit(int amountToDeposit){
    balance = balance + amountToDeposit;
    System.out.println("You just deposited "+amountToDeposit);
return amountToDeposit;
}`
а пишется как в коде в выше?

Comment: Можно, но в этом случае метод обязательно должен вернуть результат типа указанный в методе, или выбросить исключение(Exception), это стандарт. Вопросы такого характера не приветствуются на этом сайте. Пожалуйста, прочтите документацию

Comment: @d_ser зря вы так, давно были в шкуре новичка? вполне нормальный вопрос для начавшего `изучать` программирование а не `ctrl+c` `ctrl+v`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ не реже раза в год нахожусь в шкуре новичка. Основы надо изучать по учебнику.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Злые Вы. Человек  задает ввполне резонный вопрос по архитектуре о необходимости возвращать результат из практически идентичных методов. Почему при зачислении на счет возвращается входной аргумент а при изъятии средств нет.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я как раз добрый, знаю и понимаю опасность бессистемного обучения для новичка.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev При изучении по учебнику вполне могут возникать недопонимания. Задать вопрос про непонятный момент при изучении по учебнику -- вполне нормально. Не зря ведь кроме учебников существуют еще учителя. А в данном случае нет совершенно никаких оснований для вывода, что человек обучается бессистемно.

Comment: @m.vokhm полностью поддерживаю это

Comment: @d_ser Вопросы какого именно "такого" характера не поддерживаются на этом сайте? Где именно в документации есть указание на это? Можете пояснить свою мысль и дать конкретную ссылку?

Comment: @m.vokhm Не имел мысли кого-то оскорбить. Чтобы найти ответы на вопросы ссылающиеся в основу языка, было бы разумным разобраться, прочитать доступную информацию. Документацию предоставил в ответе

Answer (score 1):

Просто потому что автору взбрело в голову так написать.

Эти методы по сути одинаковые и логично чтобы они либо оба ничего не возвращали, либо чтобы оба что-то возвращали. При этом возврат аргументы видится мне действием совершенно бесполезным и если уж что-то возвращать, то значение `balance`.

Кстати, ещё охапка косяков этого кода:

- Значение `balance` можно получить только как часть строки после `toString()` - никакого геттера не предусмотрено.
- Класс явно рассматривается как единица инкапсуляции сведений о счёте, но при этом в нём же расположен метод `main()`, являющийся стартовой точкой программы. Во-первых, это уже так себе стиль, во-вторых, такое расположение позволит обращаться из него в приватным полям.
- Если классы пока не рассматривались, то я бы делал всё статическим, чтобы получилась простая однофайловая программа. А тут какой-то гибридный вариант.

Если это код из учебника, и в нём не поясняется, что что-то сделано для примера и ничего не говорится о существовании недостатков (которые будут исправляться в дальнейшем), я бы рекомендовал его сменить.

Comment: признателен Вам за адекватный и по существу ответ. Занимаюсь по "Head First" 2-е издание и параллельно на портале "codecademy" прохожу практические задания.Этот пример как раз с этого портала, и про недостатки, которые будут исправляться там ничего не сказано. Может  посоветуете еще литературу, которая мне может быть полезна в изучении?

Comment: @Alex, Head First - вроде хорошая серия. Вообще, пор книги тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416634/178988.