# Как правильно передать массив в метод?

Tags: java, syntax

Вопрос глупый, но сижу уже несколько часов. Мне нужно в созданный массив добавить кучу текстовых строк. Я хочу сделать это методом, который можно убрать подальше. Но реализация подкачала в области синтаксиса((

Я догадываюсь что ошибка в объявлении и, возможно, вызове метода. Как будет проще и правильнее написать этот кусок?

Спасибо.

P.S. Там строк под сотню, я просто убрал для примера

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    setVariables();
    ArrayList<Boolean> answers = new ArrayList<Boolean>(); // ответы да и нет
    ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<String>(); // текст вопросов
    questions.addQuestions();
}


 public static addQuestions(ArrayList<String>) {
     ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<String>();
     questions.add("У Вас чаще бывает веселое и беззаботное настроение?");
     questions.add("Вы чувствительны к оскорблениям?");
     return questions;
}
```

Comment: А можно еще и из файла их вычитывать) Вот [пример](https://devcolibri.com/%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-3-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-fileinputstream-%D0%B8-fileout/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно не передать массив в метод, а вернуть из метода заполненный `ArrayList` (не путайте с массивом, это другой тип). То, что вы пытаетесь сделать -- `questions.addQuestions();` -- это попытка вызвать метод `addQuestions()` объекта `questions`. Для того, чтобы так можно было сделать, нужно, чтобы объект `questions` относился к классу, у которого определен метод `addQuestions()`. НО у вас `questions` объявлен как объект класса `ArrayList`. У этого класса есть методы `add()`, `forEach()`, `clear()` и прочие (смотрите справку), но нет метода `addQuestions()`, именно поэтому компилятор на ваш код и ругается.
Я бы сделал вот так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    setVariables();
    ArrayList<Boolean> answers = new ArrayList<>(); // Тоже 
    List<String> questions = сreateQuestionList();
}

public static List<String> сreateQuestionList() { // Создает и возвращает список
    ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<>();
    questions.add("У Вас чаще бывает веселое и беззаботное настроение?");
    questions.add("Вы чувствительны к оскорблениям?");
    return questions;
}
```

А вообще читайте сообщения об ошибках, которые выдает компилятор. Чаще всего они прямо и недвусмысленно указывают на ошибки в вашем коде.

Прочитайте также какую-нибудь книжку по `Java` (см. [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-java)), тогда дело пойдет быстрее и шишек меньше будет.

Comment: Вопрос был касательно метода, заполняющего список, а не создающего его.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия вопрос был вообще про то, как передать массив в метод. Если начинающий пытается что-то сделать, но пока неловко и неправильно, лучше показать, как сделать то, что ему надо, ловчее и правильно, чем так же неловко, но правильно.

Comment: имя метода должно начинаться со строчной буквы, а не с заглавной

Comment: @ВладиславЭстрин Вы правы. Очепятка, не заметил второпях. Исправил.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно просто сделать `void`, которые ничего не возвращает и просто заполняет список (это не массив). В этот метод вы передаёте только ссылку на список, через которую в него добавляются элементы. И метод `addQuestions` вызывается напрямую, он относится к текущему классу, а не к списку.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    setVariables();
    ArrayList<Boolean> answers = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<String>();
    addQuestions(questions);
}


public static void addQuestions(ArrayList<String> questions) {
    questions.add("У Вас чаще бывает веселое и беззаботное настроение?");
    questions.add("Вы чувствительны к оскорблениям?");
}
```