# Машинный код Java программы

Tags: java, компиляция, компилятор, jvm

Мне надо

1. Получить машинный код, генерируемый в итоге всего пути прохождения моей Java программы в виде файла, которую можно скажем открыть через блокнот и там увидеть чисто бинарный код.
2. Увидеть сгенерированный байт-код, который еще не прошел обработку через JVM в виде файла, который при открытии скажем через блокнот, покажет тот код,  который передается JVM, если это код ассемблера, то увидеть в виде обычного кода ассемблера, если опять таки бинарный код - то увидеть в бинарном виде, а не в том непонятном виде, в котором обычно можно увидеть .class при просмотре через блокнот, уж явно код на самом деле не имеет тот вид, каким обычно показывает блокнот, а мне надо увидеть чисто тот вид кода, который передается JVM -у.

Прошу помочь.

ВАЖНО!  У меня нет задачи создать .exe или другие файлы, мне просто тупо надо получить возможность увидеть желанные коды в их правильном виде.

Желательно:

вид бинарного кода компилятора javac и бинарного кода, который уже через JVM выполняется уже компьютером - в виде файла желательно txt для исправного открытия в блокноте в таком

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или в таком

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

виде.

Comment: Байткод вы можете посмотреть с помощью утилиты [javap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html). Результат работы JIT-компилятора поможет увидеть пара ключей `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions` и `-XX:+PrintAssembly`, но с этим много тонкостей, поэтому надо хорошо понимать, как работает JVM и JIT-компиляция.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, уточняя суть своего желания. Неважно каким путем получить, даже если придется отдельной программой пользоваться - главное получить желанные коды в их правильном виде в txt или в другом расширении файла, главное чтобы была схожа или полностью такого же вида как выше в скринах-примерах.

Comment: @RubenKubalyan, никто не смотрит бинарные файлы именно в виде нулей и единиц, обычно смотрят в шестнадцатеричном виде. Для этого есть шестнадцатеричные редакторы.

Comment: @insolor Если открыто говорить, то мне не интересно кто смотрит или не смотрит в бинарном виде :)  мне самому надо иметь возможность иногда просматривать свой код в бинарном виде, ну хотя бы из за того, что по любому компьютер понимает только бинарный код а не шестнадцатеричный или восьмеричный или десятичный или ... ну сами понимаете. Возможно я ошибаюсь, но куда не гляну - написано "компьютер сам лично - понимает только бинарный код"

Comment: @RubenKubalyan, компьютер не рассматривает каждый байт отдельно по битам, а обрабатывает их целиком, как числа. Человеку рассматривать байты по отдельным битам тоже нет особого смысла - только данных на экране меньше поместится. Да и различие в одном бите трудно заметить, если в виде 0 и 1 записано. А если у вас `BD` вместо `AD` - то увидите сразу.

Comment: я не понял что конкретно вы имеете ввиду "компьютер не рассматривает каждый байт отдельно по битам, а обрабатывает их целиком, как числа.", в смысле не представил как тогда работает компьютер, но это вторично, первична для меня узнать способ получения этих бинарных кодов, ну какие бинарные коды, я написал выше в моем вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не представляю зачем вам это, но увидеть бинарное представление байткода можно так

```
public class App {
    private static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("SomeClass.class")) {
            int b, c = 0;
            while ((b = is.read()) != -1) {
                String s = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
                System.out.print(s + " ");

                if (c > SCREEN_WIDTH) {
                    System.out.println();
                    c = 0;
                } else {
                    c++;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Только нужно учесть, что оно включает не только код, но и все метаданные без разбора.

А увидеть в таком виде машинный код, генерируемый JIT-компилятором вы не сможете.

Comment: ну 50% необходимого уже есть (хотя жаль, что вместе  со всеми метаданными без разбора но все же), а про машинный код какой вариант есть? ну кроме javap, так как - как я понял, javap не все показывает.

Comment: javap показывает текстовое представление байткода. Для доступа к машинному коду понадобиться писать [нативный агент](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140680.html), получающий в рантайме доступ к JIT-кэшу виртуальной машины через JVMTI-интерфейс. Это задача чрезвычайно высокого уровня сложности.

Comment: Плохо, что сложная эта задача, хорошо, что выполнима. А так, если есть уже написанный такой шаблон, тогда это было бы очень кстати. У вас есть ссылка на сайт где есть такая программа ?

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что такая существует.

Comment: Странно, что такая тема настоль малопопулярна. Ладно тогда, какие книги с подробнейшим описанием работы JVM посоветуете прочесть? (ну хоть получу какие то шансы создать нужную мне программу для получения нужного бинарного кода и сохранения его в файл)

Comment: Ничего странного, такое представление просто не имеет практической пользы, а потому никому не нужно. Книг подобного уровня не существует, на сколько мне известно. Придётся сначала прочитать все книги из разделов "средний" и "экспертный уровень" [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416635/204271), а потом читать официальную документацию и копать исходный код OpenJDK.

Comment: Ок. Спасибо за инфо.