# С чего начать изучение JAVA?

Tags: java, ооп

Хочу научиться программировать на JAVA. Неделю назад начал активно изучать по видео урокам данный язык. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие-нибудь лайфхаки или полезные книжки, статьи, курсы и т.п.(на русском языке), чтобы можно было как можно быстрее и глубже погрузиться в изучение. Не хочется тратить время в пустую, уча что-то "не то"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если хочешь изучать с нуля, то платформа JavaRush будет очень кстати на начальном этапе. Там выдается бесплатный период, и за это время можно пройти первый раздел, где изучишь основы Java(переменные, операторы, циклы и тд.). Лично я не вижу смысла платить за остальные разделы и проходить их, так как слишком много воды будет далее и время убьешь впустую. После того как пройдешь основы, можно знакомиться с GUI, такие как JavaFX и Swing. Можно сделать небольшую программку и выложить на GitHub, скорее для портфолио. Как только разберешься со всем этим можно смело начать изучать коллекции и пробовать писать что-то для web. Главное хорошо знать Java SE. Можешь так же ознакомиться со Spring.

https://javarush.ru/ - JavaRush

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vW2Y7r-vbNw&t=19s - Swing

https://github.com/ - GitHub

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZgXUK5L3Ss - у GeekBrains много полезного

Из литературы посоветую:

Изучаем Java (Head First Java) авт.Берт Бейтс и Кати Сьерра - тут с нуля.

Философия Java авт.Брюс Эккель  - как только начнешь ориентироваться в языке.

Answer (score 1):

1. Для начала научиться гуглить хотя бы на этом сайте ...
2. [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-java)