# Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, дорожную карту для разработчика Java?

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, desktop

Я учусь на втором курсе универститета. Изучаю C# и Python в университетской программе. Всё ограничивается лишь проектиками на понимание алгоритмов и структур данных. Это, конечно, очень полезно. Однако я хочу параллельно развиваться в стеке Java потому, что этот язык популярен в моём регионе и интересен лично мне. Также к окончанию университета или при учёбе в старших курсах уже хочу с имеющимся стеком знаний и портфолио устроиться на достойную должность Java-разработчика. Сейчас начал изучать язык программирования Java, выучил основы. Дальше хочу интенсивно двигаться вглубь этого направления. 
Пожалуйста, опытные разработчики, посоветуйте мне ту дорожную карту, которая помогла вам или которая, на ваш взгляд, подходящая для неопытного разработчика. 
Хочу специализироваться на разработке программ для ПК. Спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-java)

Comment: @Leks, не дубликат, потому что там нет, собственно, дорожной карты (тем, которые нужно изучить, и в каком порядке), а только список ресурсов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде бы, довольно таки легко это "гуглится":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изображение взято из статьи: https://dzone.com/articles/the-2019-java-developer-roadmap

Comment: Неплохо бы еще ссылку на источник

Comment: @insolor, добавил.

Answer (score 1):

Java core, Герберт Шилдт java для начинающих, 
Многопоточность,
(swing, javaFX) - десктоп UI, щас все переходит на веб не думаю что стоит затягивать, познакомиться и знать как работает.

DAO pattern,
SQL,
Servlets and JSP(щас есть ему замена themyleaf),
Hibernate,
Spring,

MVC - паттерн, так же поймёшь что нужно html + css + js а дальше куча веб фреймворков в разных компаниях используются разные фреймы. 
Я по такому принципу учусь
Чекни в комментариях ссылку.

Comment: Спасибо, очень нужный совет!