# С чего начать изучение Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Уже несколько месяцев изучаю `Java`. Выучил `основы языка`, `Core`, `коллекции`, `дженерики`. Есть понимание `ООП`. На практике применял `stream`. Есть маленький `pet-проект` с использованием `GUI Swing`. Умею писать простейшие `sql-запросы`. Понимаю, что уже надо изучать `Spring`, но не знаю с чего начать. Особо большого выбора видео-курсов на просторах `youtube` нет. Кто-то показывает как работать с `MVC`, а кто показывает полный `Spring` без должных комментариев, разобраться сложно. На форумах пишут, что лучше начать со `Spring Boot`, но из полезного материала ничего посоветовать не могут. Возможно, ответ найду тут. Хочу получить самые базовые понятия по `Spring`, и посмотреть как это используется на практике.

Литература, которую я уже прочел:

Java: Head First, Философия Java, курсы JavaRush;

Sql: Sql для простых смертных(лит-ра);

Spring: Совсем недавно стал читать Spring в движении(этого не достаточно).

Comment: ИМХО изучать надо на практике. Попробуйте соорудить API, которое будет хранить в БД 2 сущности со связью один-ко-многим и выдавать доступ на чтение-запись только для авторизованных (опционально через соц.сети) пользователей. На мой взгляд это и будет необходимый минимум знаний.

Comment: Начинайте изучение с Servlet API.

Comment: Не знаю как лучше, но я начинал с этого сайта https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/index.htm и документации самого Spring`а.

Comment: Лучше всего начать с видео индусов на youtube))
Вообще курсы и видео с youtube  не плохие варианты, когда нет представления о фреймворке. Если выбирать курсы, то лучше те, в которых бы была проверка кода человеком. Если видео то от Яндекс [нашел](https://zen.yandex.ru/media/id/5ac20956168a91ffeae449c5/spring-boot-delaem-prostoe-veb-prilojenie-na-java-prostoi-sait-5ac33f542f578c01b35b02b9)

Comment: Добавлю немного к комментарию @АлексейОсецкий - там по ссылке видео от lets Code, у него канал на ютуб и не плохой курс по спрингу. Разбирает очень многие части и весьма последовательно.

Comment: А мне советовали Spring - потрошителя посмотреть

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам начал заниматься изучением Spring, вот мои советы:

1. Здесь показаны необходимы примеры + официальная документация: [ссылка](https://spring.io/guides#tutorials)
2. По этому видеоуроку неплохо подтянул знания, он разбирает задания с [оф. сайта](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jH17YkBTpI4&t=2s)
3. Телеграм-канал, где помогают друг другу с вопросами по Spring: springframeworkio (не реклама, сам редко там сижу).
4. Вполне можно с него начать, чтобы просто посмотреть как выглядит написание кода на Spring: [ссылка](https://o7planning.org/ru/11267/spring-boot-tutorial-for-beginners)
5. Также советую посмотреть здесь [статью](https://habr.com/ru/post/484130/), я сам сейчас её изучаю, посмотреть можно.
6. Список [книг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-java).

По поводу книг однозначно сказать не могу, но когда начинал читать, то уже более опытный программисты сказали не заострять на этом внимание и лучше почитать оф. документацию, потому что российские переводчики не успевают переводить книги от разработчиков Spring и актуальную информацию вряд ли получишь. НО, если хорошо знаешь английский, то вполне можно почитать последние выпущенные книги от них.

Comment: "Spring в действии" Уоллса издан для Spring 3 в 2013-м году, но всё ещё не потерял актуальности. Java и enterprise-фреймворки не меняются десятилетиями.

Answer (score 1):

https://spring.io/ вот от сюда разбирать примеры. и как накопиться нормально опыта сделать свою супер-упрощенную копию какого нибудь сервиса. например кинопоиск, но чтобы можно было только добавлять фильмы и голосовать за них.

Answer (score 1):

До того, как изучать Spring, стоит изучить стандарты Java EE, вокруг которых он построен. Что касается изучения самого Spring, есть [прекрасные учебники](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416634/204271).

Comment: Не стоит копать в глубь, пока нет знаний в ширь