# Полностью новичок! Как выучить джаву так,чтобы не почувствовать себя умственноотсталой

Tags: java

Полностью новичок!  Как выучить джаву так,чтобы не почувствовать себя умственно отсталой. Учу джаву по онлайн курсу на сайте юдеми, встряла на arraylist, collections. Ну вообще в голову не лезет,  а если и полезет, то на следующий день будто ничего и не учила.  Образование у меня лингвистическое, но очень сильно тянет меня в IT. Мне 30 лет, есть годовалый ребенок. (время для учебы ограниченно). Поставила себе цель что за год выучу java basic.  Может кто знает какие-нибудь интернет-ресурсы где все, прям для таких чайников, как я, разжевано-показано?

Comment: Понимаю вашу боль, но вы не по адресу. В гугл гораздо больше советов подобного рода. А здесь скорее практические задачи

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-java)

Comment: Даже не знаю, чего в этом вопросе больше: нытья или оправданий

Answer (score 2):

Даже если вы и лингвист, вы работали с набором правил. Правила - это основы логики.
Что вы делали будучи лингвистом если не понимали правило - учили и выучивали. Память у человека ассоциативная не даётся Collections и в частности ArraList вводите близкие вам ассоциации. ArrayList - тетрадь со страницами у каждой есть порядковый номер и содержимое. Страницы однотипные и так далее.

Answer (score 1):

Могу посоветовать книгу - Head First Java. При желании можете найти в интернете электронную версию.

Сам её как раз дочитываю сейчас и доволен что взял. Повествование в ней старается вести себя подходящим для человека еще не вошедшего в эту сферу, потому есть много аналогий и объяснений на обыденных примерах. Впрочем должен предупредить что так или иначе после прочтения главы могут оставаться белые пятна и потому нужно понимать что даже для освоения в более-менее полном объеме данного там материала порой придется искать ответы на свои вопросы в интернете.