# Java - что учить новичку, чтобы пройти на должность джуна

Tags: java

Хочу стать java-разработчиком. Учусь на программиста, но языки преподают другие.
Вопрос в следующем: перечислите все, что мне понадобится, чтобы попасть на должность джуна. Все технологии, может ещё доп. языки какие требуют. Знания ещё чего необходимо. Может какие проекты желательно до собесов в процессе обучения сделать и на гитхаб выложить или для себя просто написать их, может даже по уровням знаний. В общем, если у вас есть время перечислить это все, то буду очень благодарен. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: нет такого списка в природе, у каждой компании свое понятие джуна. Вам надо просто выучить максимум из того, что вы можете. Если же вы говорите о конкретной компании, то там и узнавайте, какие требования. Если вы материалы ищете, то вам [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416634/179763).

Comment: Думаю, для джуна хватит ocja сертификата

Comment: Вот только ей богу не надо учить максимум из того что можете. Потому что потом ребята пытаются выучить все, а понимания нужно ли им это или нет нет. Есть вещи которые нужно знать, а есть вещи которые если понадобится можно выучить

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить ответы на все эти вопросы, открываем любой работный сайт и смотрим требования к вакансиям - обычно там пишут тот стек технологий, с которым они работают - вот это и надо учить, если конечно оно тебе самому интересно.

Можно ещё все тоже самое на собеседовании спросить - может они тебе порекомендуют, на что внимание обратить, что подучить.

Напиши своё что-нибудь, что **тебе** интересно. Например, тетрис - это общеобразовательная игра в широком смысле этого слова! Что учишь - на том и пиши, что самому интересно и что в работе пригодиться может.