# Как выучить Java с нуля?

Tags: java

Я хочу выучить Java с нуля. Я абсолютный новичок и не знаю даже основ этого языка. Я уже читал что перед изучением любого языка программирования нужно построить план. Но я не понимаю как его построить.
Я не знаю с чего мне начать. Может быть пройти полный курс на JavaRush, а потом укрепить знания книгами? или это так не работает?
Расскажите пожалуйста с чего мне начать и как построить план. Какие ресурсы мне использовать? Может даже поделитесь своим опытом в изучении.

Comment: Вообще книги для того и предназначены что бы изучать по ним. Возьмите какую нибудь книгу для начального уровня. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-java

Comment: [Jetbrains Academy](https://hyperskill.org/onboarding/?_ga=2.149951346.593073812.1595238312-644748464.1587370533&track=java)

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, лучше всего теоретические знания совмещать с практикой. Читать книжки - это, конечно же, хорошо, но если не набивать руку, решая различные задачки (которых в интернете и в этих самых книгах полно), то толку будет мало. Главное, так же, не бояться ошибок и трудностей. Как говориться, если какая-то задача кажется тебе сложной - значит ты двигаешься в нужном направлении и, решив ее, ты научишься новому.
Подытожу то, что хотел донести: постоянно практикуйся, не бойся нового и непонятного, не бойся задавать вопросы и будет тебе счастье. Удачи в начинаниях)